# python bind a type to a variable

Tags: python, variables

I am a Python noob.

I create a class as follows:

```
class t1:
    x = ''
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class t2:
    y = ''
    z = ''
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.y = t1.__init__(x)
        self.z = z
```

Now contrary to C++ or Java, I do not bind the data type to y while writing the class definition. It is only because the constructor code is such that it shows that y is of type t1.
Can we bind a data type while declaring y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  Variables in Python do not have types - `y` does not have a type.  At any moment in time, `y` refers to an object, and that object has a type.  This:

```
y = ''
```

binds `y` to an object of type `str`.  You can change it later to refer to an object of a different type.  `y` itself has no intrinsic type.

See [Fredrik Lundh's excellent "Reset your brain" article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm) for further explanation.

(By the way, this: `self.y = t1.__init__(x)` is a rather strange piece of code.  Did you mean to say `self.y = t1(x)`?)

Comment: no i meant t1.__init__(x) without the assignment. self.y = t1(x) also makes sense.
thanks

Comment: *object of type `str`* you mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's out of the scope, but please note:

```
class A(object):
    x = None
```

In this context, x is a class variable, not an instance variable and is shared by each instance. It's commonly used in the [borg pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318406/why-is-the-borg-pattern-better-than-the-singleton-pattern-in-python).

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.y = None
        self.x = x
```

Here, self.y and self.x are instance variables.