# issue with singleton python call two times __init__

Tags: python, singleton, init

I have a singleton like this

```
class Singleton:

    class __impl:
        def __init__(self):
            print "INIT"

    __instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        # Check whether we already have an instance
        if Singleton.__instance is None:
            Singleton.__instance = Singleton.__impl()

        # Store instance reference as the only member in the handle
        self.__dict__['_Singleton__instance'] = Singleton.__instance

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        """ Delegate access to implementation """
        return getattr(self.__instance, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        """ Delegate access to implementation """
        return setattr(self.__instance, attr, value)
```

When I made several instances of Singleton I get two calls to **init** , I mean "INIT" is printed two times, and I supose that it shouldn't happened

Somebody has an idea of what is wrong with this or has a better way to implement this??

Comment: Are you aware of `__new__()`?  You seem to be doing some contortions to be able to jam this pattern in to `__init__()`.

Comment: Works perfectly for me... Can you show the code you are using to test it?

Comment: I tried with __new__ but I cant,

Comment: There is to much code and I'm not able to share it...

Comment: are you by any chance subclassing this?

Comment: Use 'traceback.print_stack()` to print the stack in the `__impl.__init__`. that should give you some hints as to why its being called twice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler way to write a Singleton:

```
class Singleton(object):
    __instance = None
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super(Singleton,cls).__new__(cls)
            cls.__instance.__initialized = False
        return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self):      
        if(self.__initialized): return
        self.__initialized = True
        print ("INIT")

a = Singleton()
b = Singleton()
print (a is b)
```

although there may be better ways.  I have to admit that I've never been fond of singletons.  I much prefer a factory type approach:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

def foo_singleton_factory(_singleton= Foo()):
    return _singleton

a = foo_singleton_factory()
b = foo_singleton_factory()
print (a is b)
```

This has the advantage that you can keep getting the same instance of Foo if you want it, but you're not limited to a single instance if you decide 10 years down the road that you don't want a true singleton.

Comment: here How come a and b are same? Isn't its going to give you different instances of singleton?

Comment: @codemuncher -- in which version?  In the first version, you see that on the first call, it sets `cls.__instance` and then keeps returning the same `cls.__instance` on subsequent calls.  In the second version, it creates the singleton when the function is created and then keeps returning that value (unless you pass a different value for `_singleton`).

Comment: second version, for my next call b = foo_singleton_factory(), isn't it gonna create another object, I'm confused .

Comment: Nope, default arguments are only evaluated once -- when the function is created.  They do not get re-evaluted for subsequent calls.  This is the source of all sorts of confusion in python :-).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument for another case where it gets people.

Comment: This does not work if you inherit the Singleton class

Comment: @mgilson It works perfectly but I'm confused in the first version.
why doesn't it create a second instance? 
thanks

Answer (score 10):

[PEP 318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) has an example of a singleton decorator for classes:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = {}
    def getinstance():
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls()
        return instances[cls]
    return getinstance

@singleton
class MyClass:
    ...
```

(though I haven't used it myself.)

Btw, about...

> I made a singleton like this

Also, you should mention that you [copied it directly from ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558-the-singleton-pattern-implemented-with-python/).

Comment: I'd add def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = cls(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 3):

Since we're all ignoring your question and instead proposing alternative singleton implementations, I'll pitch in with my favourite. It takes advantage of the fact that a python module is only loaded once, no matter how many times you import it.

It's also based on the python motto "*we're all consenting adults here*" since, if you REALLY want to, you *can* instantiate it multiple times... but then you really have to put in an extra effort to do it wrong.

So in `mysingleton.py`:

```
class SingletonClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # There's absolutely nothing special about this class
        # Nothing to see here, move along
        pass

# Defying PEP8 by capitalizing name
# This is to point out that this instance is a Singleton
Singleton = SingletonClass()

# Make it a little bit harder to use this module the wrong way
del SingletonClass
```

Then use it like this:

```
from mysingleton import Singleton

# Use it!
```

I said you had to put in an extra effort to do things wrong. Here's how you could create two instances of the singleton class, making it a singleton no more:

```
another_instance = Singleton.__class__()
```

So how do you avoid this problem? I'll quote the doctor: *don't do that then!*

---

**NOTE: This was added after the comments below were made**

While I'm at it, here's another singleton variant that minimizes the amount of complicated code. It uses metaclasses:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    # All singleton methods go in the metaclass
    def a_method(cls):
        return cls.attribute

    # Special methods work too!
    def __contains__(cls, item):
        return item in cls.a_list

class Singleton(object):
    __metaclass__ = SingletonMeta
    attribute = "All attributes are class attributes"

    # Just put initialization code directly into the class
    a_list = []
    for i in range(0, 100, 3):
        a_list.append(i)

print Singleton.a_method()
print 3 in Singleton
```

In python 3 you'd create the singleton instance like this instead:

```
class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    attribute = "One... two... five!"
```

Now this one is a little more iffy, since the singleton is a *class*, and you can make *instances* of the *singleton*. In theory this is OK, since the singleton will still be a singleton even if it has instances, but you need to remember that `Singleton()` is not the singleton -- `Singleton` is! It might even suit your needs to have the singleton attributes readily available to its instances as class attributes.

Comment: I like this one.  The only thing I don't like is that you really have an instance and you can't customize the instances creation at all.  e.g. you can't do `Singleton('foo','bar','baz')` (Unless you provide `__call__`, but then you can't use `__call__` for other purposes ...)

Comment: This is good advice. The easiest way to create a singleton is to just instantiate the class once!

Comment: Nice one, real singleton. Oddly, it can still be sub-classed after deletion using `class AnotherClass(Singleton.__class__): pass` and a function ("method") defined in `SingletonClass` like `def boo(self): print 'boo!'` still works on an instance of `AnotherClass`. Along those lines, **`b = Singleton.__class__()` also works...** `isinstance(b, Singleton.__class__)` (obviously?) gives `True`.

Comment: ...(contd. from `b = Singleton.__class__()`): `b is Singleton` is `False`

Answer (score 1):

An other way:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                    return cls._instance
            except AttributeError:
                    val = cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
                    return val
```

Used as:

```
>>> class A(Singleton): pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a2 is a
True
>>> class B(Singleton): pass
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b2 = B()
>>> b2 is b
True
>>> b is a
False
>>> class D(Singleton):
...     def __init__(self, v): self.v = v
... 
>>> d = D(1)
>>> d.v
1
```

If you are worried about multiple calls to `__init__` then the choice is between using a decorator or a metaclass.

Overriding the `__new__` method allow multiple `__init__` calls because python always calls the `__init__` method of an object returned by `__new__` if the value returned is an instance of that class.

Anyway I think using a decorator it's the best thing, because it's probably the simpler solution.

If you want to know more ways of creating a singleton in python read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) question.

By the way, if you want to have all instances with the same state(and not identity) then you might be interested in the [Borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/) pattern.
If you are unsure which one to choose, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318444/510937) answer.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with all the magic that goes into `__new__` and how to use it effectively, but my impression is that this will still call `__init__` multiple times on the same instance (which is what I think OP was trying to avoid)

Comment: Yes @mgilson you are correct. I've often used this method because I did not care much about multiple init calls.
I've added a brief explanation about why this methods does multiple init calls.