# What are the use cases for Python's __new__?

Tags: python

I understand what `__new__` does (and how it's different from `__init__`) so I'm not interested in definitions, I'm interested in when and how to use `__new__`.

The documentation says:

> In general, you shouldn't need to override `__new__` unless you're subclassing an immutable type like `str`, `int`, `unicode` or `tuple`

But I can't think of other cases to use `__new__` or how to use it correctly (for example when subclassing an immutable type or why it's needed in this case).

So, when, why and how do you need to use `__new__`?

**I'm interested in the use cases, not what it does (I know what it does).**

Comment: @McFarlane: I know that, I'm interested on the situations when you need to use __new__ (more than that phrase of "subclassing an immutable type". **This is not a duplicate.**

Comment: @close voters This is not a duplicate. The referenced question asks *why `__init__` is always called after `__new__`* (it's not). This question asks for practical use cases for `__new__`. An answer for this question is not an answer for that question.

Comment: @lazyr: hope you don't mind, I incorporated your comment into the question. Thanks!

Comment: What, *another* close voter? Please *read* the text. It says: "This question covers *exactly* the same content as earlier questions on this topic. Its answers *may be merged with* another identical question" (emphasis mine). **This is not the case.** The answers in the combined question will look out-of-place!

Comment: You'll find very good use case in [What is a metaclass in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/)

Comment: @Tichodroma Did you read the question, the alledged duplicate, the comments, and close reason description? Would you care to explain why you still thought it appropriate to close this question?

Comment: @lazyr As far as I can tell, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init At leaset four other users thought so, too. If this ist wrong, please vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @Tichodroma So in other words, you honestly think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12835637/566644) may be merged in as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)?

Comment: @lazyr I voted to close the question when it was called 'Python - When, why and how do you need to use `__new__`'. The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/647772) to the referenced question answers this original title. So, yes, I think this here is a duplicate.

Comment: @Tichodroma First, it's not enough to read the title to determine if it's a duplicate. The first sentence after the title was this: *"I understand what `__new__` does (and how it's different from `__init__`)"*. Second, even if it was a duplicate then (and it wasn't), it isn't now, so you *should* vote to reopen.

Comment: @lazyr I've voted to reopen this question. Can we settle this now?

Comment: @Donal Fellows Could you also please consider undoing your close vote?

Comment: @BasicWolf I'd like you as well to please read the comments and see if you're still convinced this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering for myself, I've used it to

- create a singleton pattern (though there are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305625/566644) to do that without using `__new__`)
- [dynamically extend classes from external modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714744/566644) without actually editing the source
- customize classes in a metaclass (though `__call__` may also be used I think)
- extend a the `datetime.datetime` class (which is immutable) to return the current time if instanciated without arguments and the result of calling `strptime` on the argument if called with a single string argument

You need `__new__` when subclassing an immutable type if you want to alter the arguments used to construct the immutable, as I wanted in the `datetime` example, or if you don't want to call the parent `__new__` at all but return an instance created another way or even of an entirely different type. By the time you're in `__init__` it's too late to alter the object in any way, so you need to do it in `__new__`.

Comment: Can you share how you did the 4th point. Extend the `datetime.datetime` class.....

Answer (score 2):

A potential use case could be a "factory class" which returns instances of various classes depending on the implementation.