# Python class inherited singleton inits instance on every call

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, singleton, metaclass

I'm trying to implement class inherited singleton as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) (Method 2). Going over the question and the [extensive chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/4890123) I tried to implement the following:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance._initialized = False

        return cls._instance

class A(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init is called"

class B(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init is called"
```

As you may guess, whenever I create `Class A` I get the same object, but `__init__` is called. This is problematic as the `Class A` can have all it's members changed due to this.

Doing:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()
print a1 == a2
```

Will result in:

```
>> Init is called
>> Init is called
>> True
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12305142/4890123) poses a similar issue but I would prefer not to use the solution there as it doesn't include the inheritance and I have at least 2 classes that needs the `Singleton` inheritance. I tried to implement the solution [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577208-singletonsubclass-with-once-initialization/) but it didn't work. The [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305404/4890123) works but it involves changing `Class A` and `Class B` which I would prefer not to.

Is there a way to change the `Singleton` implementation so that `__init__` won't be called on every creation? (I can't use metaclasses as both `A` and `B` inherit other classes e.g. abstract classes with their own metaclasses).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern Python this could be done by writting a `__init_subclass__` method that  could decorate `__init__` to make it check `cls._instance` before running.

As it is, (i.e. you need it for Python 2 as well) - I think the simpler thing is for `__new__` to patch `__init__` with a NOP method if the instance already exists:

```py
_nop_init = lambda self, *args, **kw: None

class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(cls._instance, cls):
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance._initialized = False
        # Python 2 have to check in the cls.__dict__ - Py3 could check the attribute directly:
        elif cls.__dict__.get("__init__", None) is not _nop_init:
            cls.__init__ = _nop_init
        return cls._instance

class A(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init is called"

class B(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init is called"
```

**extra info** The language mechanism to call `__init__` is built-in the `__call__` method of `type` - the metaclass for all classes in Python. It will call the `__new__` and `__init__` method of a target class when instantiating it, and thus, with a metaclass, it is easy to control these calls from a custom metaclass. It is also interesting to note that when `__new__` does not return an instance of the target class, `__init__` is not called. (In this singleton case, the singleton *is* an instance of te class, and thus it is called).

**real world example**: last time I coded a singleton, I opted for avoiding re-run `__init__` in its own code - sine it is the only singleton in the project, tere was no need for generic code for that in a `__new__`:
https://github.com/jsbueno/pythonchain/blob/1f9208dc8bd2741a574adc1bf745d218e4314e4a/pythonchain/block.py#L276