# How to make a function do reverse of its job Python

Tags: python, function, reverse

How do you make a function do reverse of what it was programmed to do in Python without reprogramming the entire function?
For example:

```
swap1 = "abc"
swap2 = "def"
def swap():
    global swap1, swap2
    swap1 = swap2
```

into

```
swap1 = "abc"
swap2 = "def"
def swap():
    global swap1, swap2
    swap2 = swap1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sprinkle pixie dust on it and wave your magic wand.

Comment: "Vote down if needed"? Is this a troll question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to 'reverse' a function. Only rewriting it is possible. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

A function can only do what it's designed to do.  While some functions, by design, are reversible, there is no way to create a general case `reverse` function.  Furthermore, many functions (notably [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)) are intentionally designed to not be reversible, either simply because information is [lost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_data_conversion) along the way, or because it is intentionally [computationally impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to reverse.

You would do better to rethink your design here - the pattern you demonstrated above using `global`s is [*highly undesirable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011056/how-to-avoid-global-variables), it will lead to very complex, difficult to maintain or understand code.

Answer (score 3):

in general there is no such way to do this. the computer cannot know what you mean by "reverse", since there are different ways of the "reverse of a function".