# What is wrong with this? Python Code

Tags: python

I am trying to make a background show up but it keeps coming with a error???
Here is the code..

```
import pygame, sys

# == (1) Create 'global' variables ==
# These are variables that every part of your
# code can 'see' and change
global screen, current_keys


# == (2) Define the functions for each task first ==

# == GameInit ==
# Put initialisation stuff here
# it is called just once
# at the beginning of our game
def GameInit():
    global screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,640))

spaceship = pygame.image.load("Space Ship.png")
Background = pygame.image.load("Space Background.png")
backrect = Background.get_rect()
shiprect = spaceship.get_rect()
shiprect = shiprect.move(448, 240)

# == GameLoop ==
# Put things that have to occur repeatedly
# here. It is called every frame
def GameLoop():
    global current_keys

    # Lock the timing to 60 frames per second
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

    # Check for exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # update our key states
    current_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #if up or down move the Space Ship
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    shiprect = shiprect.move(0, -20)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    shiprect = shiprect.move(0, 20)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    shiprect = shiprect.move(-20, 0)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    shiprect = shiprect.move(20, 0) 

    # GameUpdate functions will go here
    # GameDraw functions will go here

    #Drawing the characters & Background
    screen.blit(Background, backrect)
    screen.blit(spaceship, shiprect)

    # flip the screen
    pygame.display.flip()

# == (3) Call the functions to run the game ==
# We have only *defined* our functions above.
# Here we actually call them to make them happen
GameInit()
while True:
    GameLoop()`
```

and here is the error

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\Desktop\Python Subline Games\Space Game.py", line 70, in <module>
    GameLoop()
  File "C:\Users\Naeem\Desktop\Python Subline Games\Space Game.py", line 60, in GameLoop
    screen.blit(spaceship, shiprect)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shiprect' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 7.2s]
```

Comment: Once you get this working you might want to make a post over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because there's a number of things about your code that could be improved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Answer (score 2):

`shiprect` is not defined as global within `GameLoop()`.

Try adding `global shiprect` to the beginning of that function.

(Edit: this is generally considered bad practice for many reasons: [How to avoid global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011056/how-to-avoid-global-variables))

Comment: no, you rarely (if ever) need to use globals. Passing the variable to the function is much better.

Comment: wait where do I have to add it? which function?

Comment: @GuyNaeem in the function `GameLoop()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you define a value outside of a function, and want to use it inside a function, pass it to the function as a parameter:

```
foo = 1

def bar(foo):
    foo += 1
    return foo
```

So, in your case, pass `shiprect` to your `GameLoop()` function:

```
...
shiprect = shiprect.move(448, 240)

def GameLoop(shiprect):
    ...
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        shiprect = shiprect.move(0, -20)

...
while True:
    GameLoop(shiprect)
```

Comment: This will not work - shiprect will be the same at each iteration of the main loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it helped a lot! But the ship goes up then it just comes down again