# Python: update instance variable of parent class in child class

Tags: python-3.x

I searched quite a bit on this, but can't seem to find anything specific to my problem.

Say I have three separate python files fileA.py, fileB.py, and fileMain.py

fileB.py inherits from fileA.py.

fileA.py

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.valueA = 5
```

fileB.py

```
from fileA import Parent

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__():
        self.valueB = 10

    def Calculate(self):
        self.result = self.valueB + self.valueA
        print(self.result)
```

And in fileMain.py I have some code that calls upon the Calculate method in the Child class AFTER valueA in the Parent class has been changed.

```
from fileA import Parent
from fileB import Child

class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = Parent()
        self.child = Child()

        self.parent.valueA = 8

        self.child.Calculate()

foobar=MainProgram()
```

My problem is, that the printed output is 15 and not 18. Why? How could I resolve this to get the expected result?

The reason I want for fileB.py to inherit from fileA.py is that I plan on having a fileC.py also inherit from fileA.py and have other calculations done there also using self.valueA. The valueA is supposed to be set by the user of the program. I simplified things here. Hope this makes sense?

Sorry if my use of terminology is wrong. Please correct me. :)

Comment: Hint: move `self.child = Child()` to underneath `self.parent.valueA = 8`.

Comment: @Mr.Zeus that won't change anything

Comment: Whoops, sorry, should have thought it through.

Comment: Why does that not change anything?

Comment: Files do not inherit from files. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to not be clear on how `classes` and `instances` (also referred to as `objects`) work.

`Parent`, `Child` and `MainProgram` are `classes`. You can think of them as blueprints. They *do not change*.

When you instantiate a class, you get an `instance`, e.g:

```
parent = Parent()
child = Child()
```

`parent` and `child` are instances. When you call `parent.valueA = 8` you are changing a value on the `instance` called `parent`.

When you call `child.Calculate()` it has nothing to do with the `parent` instance. When you instatiated `Child()` the `Parent()` constructor was called and so `child.valueA` was set to equal `5`. You would need to call `child.valueA = 8` in order to change it.

For more information, consider reading through this: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

(EDIT: By the way you refer to fileB inhereting from fileA and so forth. This an incorrect use of terminology. A file does not *inherit* from another *file*. You would say a module *imports* from another *module*. A class *inherits* from another *class*)

EDIT2:

If your goal is to share the `state` of `Parent` between all it's instances, you can use a Borg pattern for it. Essentially, every instance of the Borg shares its state with all other instances. So if you do `parent1 = Parent()` and `parent2 = Parent()`, and then do `parent1.valueA = 8`, then `parent2.valueA` will also equal `8`.

It works like this:

```
class Parent(object): #This is a Borg class
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        self.valueA = 5


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self.valueB = 10

    def Calculate(self):
        self.result = self.valueB + self.valueA
        print(self.result)


class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = Parent()
        self.child = Child()

        self.parent.valueA = 8

        self.child.Calculate()

foobar=MainProgram()
```

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment! So if I have multiple classes inheriting valueA from the same parent class, I have to assign the new value to all the child classes individually? I was hoping there would be a more efficient way.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a Borg pattern. I'll update my answer to show how it works. Personally I haven't really used it, so I can't give you the best explanation of why it works, but it will solve the problem you have. Here's an example: https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/creational/borg.py. And here is a discussion you might find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318406/why-is-the-borg-pattern-better-than-the-singleton-pattern-in-python

Comment: In Python, *everything* is an object, even classes. So there are classes and their instances. But an object may be a class, and an instance may be a class as well (all classes are instances of `type`, for example)

Comment: Yeah sure, technically speaking that is true. That doesn't help a beginner understand what is going on though. Outside the Python world `object` generally means the same as `instance` (even though there is some disagreement on that, mainly when people point to primitives: they aren't instances of anything, but the are objects; personally I prefer to refer to them as values rather than objects). Anyway,  I do only mention `object` once, but refer to `instances` throughout