# How to prevent a module from being imported twice?

Tags: python, import, module

When writing python modules, is there a way to prevent it being imported twice by the client codes? Just like the c/c++ header files do:

```
#ifndef XXX
#define XXX
...
#endif
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Python modules aren't imported multiple times. Just running import two times will not reload the module. If you want it to be reloaded, you have to use the `reload` statement. Here's a demo

`foo.py` is a module with the single line

```
print("I am being imported")
```

And here is a screen transcript of multiple import attempts.

```
   >>> import foo
   Hello, I am being imported
   >>> import foo # Will not print the statement
   >>> reload(foo) # Will print it again
   Hello, I am being imported
```

Comment: Do note that `reload()` won't fix up any references to the old module, so is not actually all that useful.

Comment: References: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules.  http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Comment: Remember as well of performing imports outside of threads whenever possible, although that rarely causes problems.

Answer (score 28):

As specified in other answers, *Python* generally doesn't reload a module when encountering a second import statement for it. Instead, it returns its cached version from `sys.modules` without executing any of its code.

However there are several pitfalls worth noting:

- Importing the main module as an ordinary module effectively creates two instances of the same module under different names.

  This occurs because during program startup [the main module is set up with the name `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html). Thus, when importing it as an ordinary module, *Python* doesn't detect it in `sys.modules` and imports it again, but with its proper name the second time around.

  Consider the file */tmp/a.py* with the following content:

  ```
  # /tmp/a.py
  import sys

  print "%s executing as %s, recognized as %s in sys.modules" % (__file__, __name__, sys.modules[__name__])
  import b
  ```

  Another file */tmp/b.py* has a single import statement for *a.py* (`import a`).
  Executing */tmp/a.py* results in the following output:

  ```sh
  root@machine:/tmp$ python a.py
  a.py executing as __main__, recognized as <module '__main__' from 'a.py'> in sys.modules
  /tmp/a.pyc executing as a, recognized as <module 'a' from '/tmp/a.pyc'> in sys.modules
  ```

  Therefore, it is best to keep the main module fairly minimal and export most of its functionality to an external module, as advised [here](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#executing-the-main-module-twice).
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798648/3903832) specifies two more possible scenarios:

  1. Slightly different import statements utilizing different entries in `sys.path` leading to the same module.
  2. Attempting another import of a module after a previous one failed halfway through.

Comment: This actually helped me solve the problem, the other answer was not complete.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Imports are cached, and only run once. Additional imports only cost the lookup time in `sys.modules`.