# Why does running the Flask dev server run itself twice?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for developing a website and while in development I run flask using the following file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from app import app
import config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('################### Restarting @', datetime.utcnow(), '###################')
    app.run(port=4004, debug=config.DEBUG, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I start the server, or when it auto-restarts because files have been updated, it always shows the print line twice:

```
################### Restarting @ 2014-08-26 10:51:49.167062 ###################
################### Restarting @ 2014-08-26 10:51:49.607096 ###################
```

Although it is not really a problem (the rest works as expected), I simply wonder why it behaves like this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

The Werkzeug reloader spawns a child process so that it can restart that process each time your code changes. Werkzeug is the library that supplies Flask with the development server when you call `app.run()`.

See the [`restart_with_reloader()` function code](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/54acdd16b247f7037482737e72ec52fc6d50a78d/src/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L160-L185); your script is run *again* with `subprocess.call()`.

If you set `use_reloader` to `False` you'll see the behaviour go away, but then you also lose the reloading functionality:

```
app.run(port=4004, debug=config.DEBUG, host='0.0.0.0', use_reloader=False)
```

You can disable the reloader when using the `flask run` command too:

```
FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run --no-reload
```

You can use the [`werkzeug.serving.is_running_from_reloader` function](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/serving/#werkzeug.serving.is_running_from_reloader) if you wanted to detect when you are in the reloading child process:

```
from werkzeug.serving import is_running_from_reloader

if is_running_from_reloader():
    print(f"################### Restarting @ {datetime.utcnow()} ###################")
```

However, if you need to set up module globals, then you should instead use the [`@app.before_first_request` decorator](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) on a function and have that function set up such globals. It'll be called just once after every reload when the first request comes in:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    print(f"########### Restarted, first request @ {datetime.utcnow()} ############")
```

Do take into account that if you run this in a full-scale WSGI server that uses forking or new subprocesses to handle requests, that `before_first_request` handlers *may* be invoked for each new subprocess.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using the modern `flask run` command, none of the options to `app.run` are used. To disable the reloader completely, pass `--no-reload`:

```
FLASK_DEBUG=1 flask run --no-reload
```

Also, `__name__ == '__main__'` will never be true because the app isn't executed directly. Use the same ideas from [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25504196), except without the `__main__` block.

```
if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') != 'true':
    # do something only once, before the reloader

if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
    # do something each reload
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by setting `app.debug` to `False`. Setting it to `True` was causing my `__name__ == "__main__"` to be called twice.

Comment: My `__main__` still runs twice with both `app.debug = False` and `app.run_server(debug=False)`. Are you sure that did it for you, or could you post some reproducible code to try?

Comment: Changing app.debug was all I did to solve it for me. Can you confirm that main is only running twice when the flask server is started? Try getting a minimal working example running and see if the issue occurs. Also try running a minimal example that fails in multiple python versions, that may have been an issue. I have since migrated my project to Java and SparkJava instead of python and flask, so I don't remember exactly what fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm using `flask` via `plotly dash`, and found out they recently [changed the default](https://github.com/plotly/dash/commit/f2ed4187ab454ee4de6368d449a9c0763899afc5#diff-228c9aefac729977642672aa1416baca) `debug` argument passed to `flask`. I'm going to guess that I was mistaken above and perhaps did `app.debug=False` (which maybe is overridden by the default args to `run_server`), or only tried without passing `True`, not explicitly setting as shown above. This is working correctly for me now (making sure that `debug=False`). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

From Flask 0.11, it's recommended to run your app with `flask run` rather than `python application.py`. Using the latter could result in running your code twice.

[As stated here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/) :

> ... from Flask 0.11 onwards the flask method is recommended. The reason for this is that due to how the reload mechanism works there are some bizarre side-effects (like executing certain code twice...)

Answer (score 2):

I am using plugin - python-dotenv
and i will put this on my config file - .flaskenv:

**FLASK_RUN_RELOAD=False**

and this will avoid flask run twice for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by modifying my main and inserting use_reloader=False into it. If anybody is here looking for a workaround for this problem then the below code will get you started, however, you will remove the functionality of changes in code being detected automatically, and restarting the application will not work. You will have to manually stop and restart your application after each edit in code.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason why the Flask app run itself twice is a configuration of `WEB_CONCURRENCY` setting on Heroku. To set into one, you can write in console
`heroku config:set WEB_CONCURRENCY=1`

Answer (score 0):

The gist of my fix was to share a tmp file among all processes, if the file does not exist, start initializing code, including set up a scheduler. All other suggestions I tried, they either lose functionality of child processes for scalability or auto reload in debugging Flask provided.

```
  import os.path
  from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

  app = Flask(__name__)

  def set_lastrun():
       f = open('/tmp/lastrun','w')
       f.write(f'{datetime.now()}')
       f.close()

  def get_lastrun():
      return os.path.isfile('/tmp/lastrun')

  def start_job_scheduler():
      scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()    
      scheduler.add_job(func=your_job, trigger="interval", seconds=300)
      scheduler.start()

  def app_init():
      if not get_lastrun():
          set_lastrun()
          start_job_scheduler()

  app_init()
```

`