# web.py hosted on Apache does not run code in side if __name__ == "__main__":

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, web.py

I have this same code which I have mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133738/web-app-starts-many-times-web-py) of mine. Now I have hosted the same web.py app on Apache. But when I start Apache the code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not executed.

Is it possible to run backgroud process(check the other question for the code) when hosted in Apache?

Why does the code inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not executed?

This is working well when web.py is run without Apache.

Comment: This issue is discussed in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/assorted-tips-and-tricks.html You can in the WSGI script file (only), use ``__name__.startswith('_mod_wsgi_')``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` doesn't run because that's not how Apache runs python code.

More likely, you're running your python under mod_wsgi or uwsgi, which is a way to have Apache talk to python.

Keep the `if __name__ == '__main__':` stuff: that's useful for simple testing, but add a similar block like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
elif under_mod_wsgi or under_uwsgi:
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    application = app.wsgifunc()  # !!rather than app.run()
```

Your `Process` stuff should still run (reference your other question).

To detect if `under_mod_wsgi` you can:

```
try:
    from mod_wsgi import version
    if version:
        pass
    under_mod_wsgi = True
except ImportError:
    under_mod_wsgi = False

try:
    import uwsgi
    under_uwsgi = True
except ImportError:
    under_uwsgi = False
```