# Python timer functions run twice with bottle.py when reloader=True

Tags: python, multithreading, bottle

While having problems with python timers I found that when bottle.py is run with "reloader = True", all timer functions run twice in rapid succession.

I have tried this with several different methods of invoking the timers and the result is the same in all instances (double firing).

The sample code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 from threading import Timer
 from bottle import *

# Short timer
def short_time():
        t = Timer(1, short_time)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        print "Short Time..."

# Long timer
def long_time():
        t = Timer(5, long_time)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        print "Long Time..."

# The App
app = Bottle()

@app.route('/status')
def default():
        return "OK"

#Run the app -----
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Start the short timer.  
    short_time()

    # Start the long timer.  
    long_time()

    # Run the app
    # This interferes with the timers
    run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8002, reloader=True) 

    #This one works as expected
    #run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8002) #This works fine
```

**The output with reloader enabled:**

```
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Long Time...
Short Time...
Long Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
```

**The expected output (without reloader):**

```
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Long Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
Long Time...
Short Time...
Short Time...
```

Any ideas on how to use reloader, but prevent the timer problem?

Comment: Related: [Why does running the Flask dev server run itself twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25504149)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `reloader=True` is set, the bottle process [re-runs the script as a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207000/python-difference-between-class-and-instance-attributes):

> ```
> if reloader and not os.environ.get('BOTTLE_CHILD'):
>     import subprocess
>     lockfile = None
>     try:
>         fd, lockfile = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='bottle.', suffix='.lock')
>         os.close(fd)  # We only need this file to exist. We never write to it
>         while os.path.exists(lockfile):
>             args = [sys.executable] + sys.argv
>             environ = os.environ.copy()
>             environ['BOTTLE_CHILD'] = 'true'
>             environ['BOTTLE_LOCKFILE'] = lockfile
>             p = subprocess.Popen(args, env=environ)
> ```

The child is then *restarted* every `interval` seconds (default 1).

Anything run at the top-level of the script is run both when you start the bottle server, and each time the child process is started again.

As such, both the parent *and* child process are running timers, independently. The long timer in the child process never gets executed as that process is killed before the 5 seconds are up, but the short timer may *just* manage to fire before the parent process kills the child to start it again.

You can detect if you are in the child process by testing for the `BOTTLE_CHILD` environment variable:

```
import os
if os.environ.get('BOTTLE_CHILD'):
    # in the child process, do something special perhaps?
    # this will be executed *each time the child is restarted*
else:
    # in the parent process, which restarts the child process
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn.  I have tested this and it works as expected.