# Why am I instantiating two different queues?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask-restful

I'm trying to set-up an application which will receive HTTP GET's and POST's using python and flask-restful. The problem that I'm getting is that when I start the application I see that there are two instances of a queue being generated. I would like you to help me understand why?

Application output (terminal):

```
<queue.Queue object at 0x10876fdd8>
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
<queue.Queue object at 0x10ce48be0>
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 292-311-362
```

Python code (ran with the following command `python -m main`):

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import requests
import os
import threading
import queue
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("endpoint")

queue = queue.Queue()

base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
config = Json_Parser().get_json_object(base_path + "path")

consumer = Consumer(config, queue)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=consumer.consume)
t1.start()


class Interaction(Resource):
    def get(self):
        self.create_interaction()
        thread_queue = consumer.get_queue()
        output = thread_queue.get()
        return output

api.add_resource(Interaction, '/interaction')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(queue)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What command do you use to start? (which generates the aformentioned **Application output**)

Comment: @RicharddeWit `python -m main`

Comment: I think it's because you are running and importing it, it gets evaluated twice. Put the `print` inside the `if` before `app.run`

Comment: Now I get double printing: 
`<queue.Queue object at 0x10c5400b8>
<queue.Queue object at 0x10c5400b8>
 ...
 * Restarting with stat
<queue.Queue object at 0x106bb8a90>
<queue.Queue object at 0x106bb8a90>`

Comment: Did you remove the `print` after the `queue = ...`?

Comment: Now I did and the output is equal to the post

Comment: Try running `python app.py` (if the filename is `app.py`) instead of `python -m main`

Comment: It does the same thing

Comment: Can you update your question with the command you used and the `print` inside the `if`?

Comment: Just to be sure: could you remove `print(thread_queue)` in the `Interaction` class and run again?

Comment: It seems it is loading two times. Should all the code outside the class go to the if block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Richar de Wit I changed the following line:

`app.run(debug=True)`

to:

`app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)`

to prevent the debugger to instantiate two queues thus giving issues later on.

The problem is referenced in this question:

[Why does running the Flask dev server run itself twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504149/why-does-running-the-flask-dev-server-run-itself-twice)

Comment: Glad to help! :)