# Thread runs twice when using Flask in Python?

Tags: python, flask

My code looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def target():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print('ok')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread(target = target, args = ()).start()
    app.run()
```

Why the target function runs twice ?? (I mean, the output is 2 `'ok'` after every 10 seconds)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It prints only once on my machine. Could you share your dependencies?

Comment: This is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504149/why-does-running-the-flask-dev-server-run-itself-twice/25504196