# Python RQ-Scheduler not giving any output

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, scheduled-tasks

I am unable to get rq_scheduler working. Here is a simple example:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
import datetime
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler

from tasks import example

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='abc'

app.redis = Redis.from_url('redis://')
app.task_queue = Queue('test', connection=app.redis)
scheduler = Scheduler(queue=app.task_queue,connection=app.redis)

#app.task_queue.enqueue('tasks.example',2)
#scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime.datetime(2020,4,16,10,46), example, 2) 
scheduler.enqueue_in(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), example, 2) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

tasks.py

```
import time

def example(seconds):
    print('Starting task')
    for i in range(seconds):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    print('Task completed')
```

In the app directory in terminal, I start the following in separate tabs:

```
$redis-server

$rq worker test

$rqscheduler

$python app.py
```

The first queue.enqueue works fine. Both scheduler tasks do nothing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you may be getting confused because `rqscheduler` by default checks for new jobs every one minute.  You can tweak this with the `-i` flag to set the interval in seconds, and also add the `-v` flag for more verbose output:

```
rqscheduler -i 1 -v
```

However I also noticed another issue with the above Flask code...

Probably due to the dev server [spawning a separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25504196/2052575) I was finding that the `scheduler.enqueue_in` function was enqueuing the job twice.  This probably wouldn't be an issue if the `enqueue_in` function was called inside a view function.  However where you have it placed this actually runs when the application is started.

So when launching with the dev server this gets executed **twice**.  This will then run **once** every time the autoreloader senses a code change: So after starting the dev server, then saving a change to the code, 3 jobs total have been enqueued.

For the purpose of testing this, it may be advisable just to have a simple python script which doesn't actually run the Flask app:

```
# enqueue_test.py

from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler

from tasks import example

r = Redis.from_url('redis://localhost:6379')
q = Queue('test', connection=r)
scheduler = Scheduler(queue=q, connection=r)
scheduler.enqueue_in(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), example, 2)
```