# Object not working properly when called from child module

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

Hello generous SO'ers,

This is a somewhat complicated question, but hopefully relevant to the more general use of global objects from a child-module.

I am using some commercial software that provides a python library for interfacing with their application through TCP.  (I can't post the code for their library I don't think.)

I am having an issue with calling an object from a child module, that I think is more generally related to global variables or some such.  Basically, the object's state is as expected when the child-module is in the same directory as all the other modules (including the module that creates the object).
But when I move the offending child module into a subfolder, it can still access the object but the state appears to have been altered, and the object's connection to the commercial app doesn't work anymore.

Following some advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python) on global vars, I have organized my module's files as so:

```
scriptfile.py
pyFIMM/
    __init__.py            # imports all the other files
    __globals.py           # creates the connection object used in most other modules
    __pyfimm.py            # main module functions, such as pyFIMM.connect()
    __Waveguide.py         # there are many of these files with various classes and functions
    (...other files...)
    PhotonDesignLib/
        __init__.py        # imports all files in this folder
        pdPythonLib.py     # the commercial library
    proprietary/
        __init__.py        # imports all files in this folder
        University.py      # <-- The offending child-module with issues
```

`pyFIMM/__init__.py` imports the sub-files like so:

```
from __globals import *         # import global vars & create FimmWave connection object `fimm`
from __pyfimm import *          # import the main module
from __Waveguide import *.
(...import the other files...)
from proprietary import *      # imports the subfolder containing `University.py`
```

The `__init__.py`'s in the subfolders "*PhotonDesignLib*" & "*proprietary*" both cause all files in the subfolders to imported, so, for example, `scriptfile.py` would access my proprietary files as so: `import pyFIMM.proprietary.University`.  This is accomplished via [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python), coded as follows in `proprietary/__init__.py`:

```
import os, glob
__all__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")]
```

(Numerous coders from a few different institutions will have their own proprietary code, so we can share the base code but keep our proprietary files/functions to ourselves this way, without having to change any base code/import statements.  I now realize that, for the more static `PhotonDesignLib` folder, this is overkill.)

The file `__globals.py` creates the object I need to use to communicate with their commercial app, with this code (this is all the code in this file):

```
import PhotonDesignLib.pdPythonLib as pd    # the commercial lib/object
global fimm
fimm = pd.pdApp()      # <- - this is the offending global object
```

All of my sub-modules contain a `from __global import *` statement, and are able to access the object `fimm` without specifically declaring it as a `global` var, without any issue.

So I run `scriptfile.py`, which has an import statement like `from pyFIMM import *`.
Most importantly, `scriptfile.py` initiates the TCP connection made to the application via `fimm.connect()` right at the top, before issuing any commands that require the communication, and all the other modules call `fimm.Exec(<commands for app>)` in various routines, which has been working swimmingly well - the `fimm` object has so-far been accessible to all modules, and keeps it's connection state without issue.

**The issue I am running into is that the file `proprietary/University.py` can only successfully use the `fimm` object when it's placed in the pyFIMM root-level directory (ie. the same folder as `__globals.py` etc.).**  But when `University.py` is imported from within the `proprietary` sub-folder, it gives me an *"application not initialized"* error when I use the `fimm` object, as if the object had been overwritten or re-initialized or something.  The object still exists, it just isn't maintaining it's connection state when called by this sub-module.  (I've checked that it's not reinitialized in another module.)

If, after the script fails in `proprietary/University.py`, I use the console to send a command eg. `pyFimm.fimm.Exec(<command to app>)`, *it communicates just fine*!
I set `proprietary/University.py` to print a `dir(fimm)` as a test right at the beginning, which works fine and looks like the `fimm` object exists as expected, but a subsequent call in the same file to `fimm.Exec()` indicates that the object's state is not correct, returning the *"application not initialized"* error.
This almost looks like there are two `fimm` objects - one that the main python console (and pyFIMM modules) see, which works great, and another that `proprietary/University.py` sees which doesn't know that we called `fimm.connect()` already.  Again, if I put `University.py` in the main module folder "*pyFIMM*" it works fine - the `fimm.Exec()` calls operate as expected!

FYI `proprietary/University.py` imports the `__globals.py` file as so:

```
import sys, os, inspect
ScriptDir = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename   # get path to this module file
(ParentDir , tail) = os.path.split(ScriptDir)       # split off top-level directory from path
(ParentDir , tail) = os.path.split(ParentDir)       # split off top-level directory from path
sys.path.append(ParentDir)        # add ParentDir to the python search path

from __globals import *         # import global vars & FimmWave connection object

global fimm         # This line makes no difference, was just trying it.
```

(FYI, Somewhere on SO it was stated that `inspect` was better than `__file__`, hence the code above.)

**Why do you think having the sub-module in a sub-folder causes the object to lose it's state?**

I suspect the issue is either the way I instruct `University.py` to import `__globals.py` or the "import all files in this folder" method I used in `proprietary/__init__.py`.  But I have little idea how to fix it!

Thank you for looking at this question, and thanks in advance for your insightful comments.

Comment: I suspect you are running into the problem describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798589/what-could-cause-a-python-module-to-be-imported-twice): `__global` is being imported twice via two different paths, because you're adding its directly explcitly to the path.  The import code you show is extremely baroque.  Why are you doing those `sys.path` manipulations?  If `university` is within the enclosing `pyFIMM` package, it should just import `globals` via a relative import like `from ..__globals import *`.

Comment: I did not know you could do relative imports like that in Py2.7!  I shall try it now...

Comment: Your solution works very well! Also your comment on importing from two different paths is great - that certainly didn't occur to me. If you post that as an answer I'll gladly accept it. As to why I was using the archaic `sys.path` manipulations, it seems the `..__mod` technique you show [wasn't available a few years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python), so I've been using the baroque method for years. I humbly bow in honor of your python prowess! 8 hours of frustration concluded within 10 minutes of posting on SO... amazing.