# How to provide Django error codes that are not hardcoded

Tags: django

I'm currently implementing some [System Checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/checks/) of my own, and noticed that Django recommends using hardcoded error identifiers, like so:

```
        Error(
            'an error',
            hint='A hint.',
            obj=checked_object,
            id='myapp.E001',
        )
```

I thought that maybe this is merely serving tutorial purposes, but turns out [that's actually how they do it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2c5d6dc44779448de1497f32c925c96975fae461/django/contrib/auth/checks.py#L34).

From the same code above, I noticed that they use a prefix scheme for identifying the type of message that is being created (e.g. E for Error, W for Warning, C for Critical, etc).

But I don't understand the numbering system. You just enter any three digit number and that's it? What happens if there's a collision? Has anyone come across a better paradigm to manage the error codes?

Comment: It is *per app* (the `myapp` prefix), so that means that as long as you distributed numbers for your app without overlap, it is fine.

Comment: Programmers define these code numbers ensuring that they do not clash, sometimes keeping ranges in between for later to group similar error types ( jumps by 100 etc.)

Comment: So it's a manual process. This could very easily escape a merge review.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand the numbering system. You just enter any three digit number and that's it? What happens if there's a collision?

**No**, you use the app name as prefix:

```
Error(
    'an error',
    hint='A hint.',
    obj=checked_object,
    id='myapp.E001',  # ← myapp prefix
)
```

as long as for an app there is no overlap, that is fine.

Strictly speaking you can make some sort of dispatcher that will generate new numbers, but that seems overkill. You could use something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_error_code(app_name, type):
    items = make_error_code.data[app_name]
    counter = items.get(type, 0) + 1
    items[type] = counter
    return f'{app_name}.{type}{counter:03}'

make_error_code.data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
```

You can then make errors with the `make_error_code`:

```
Error(
    'an error',
    hint='A hint.',
    obj=checked_object,
    id=make_error_code('my_app', 'E')  # my_app.E001
),
Error(
    'an error',
    hint='A hint.',
    obj=checked_object,
    id=make_error_code('my_app', 'W')  # my_app.W001
),
Error(
    'an error',
    hint='A hint.',
    obj=checked_object,
    id=make_error_code('my_app', 'E')  # my_app.E002
)
```

In that cas you thus define the errors as *constants* where you construct the error *once* and then use that error in the functions you define.

But for error codes that are typically scoped per app, it looks like overkill.

Comment: In case of any change to the flow of execution (say, an if statement), the codes are not generated in the proper order. I thought of this approach, TBH, but it makes the error codes undocumentable.

Comment: @AndréFratelli: no not per se. You can make use of "reflection" to automatically document the errors. You simply look at the local variables that are instantiated and then automatically generate (HTML) documentation.

Comment: Also, I understand the app prefix, but I'm concerned about multiple people working on the same package.

Comment: @AndréFratelli: well a professor once said to me that "coding skills are less important than people skills in software". If multiple people work on the same project, you need to communicate (daily standups, pull request reviews, etc.).

Comment: Hmm.. So the error the codes would be versioned. I'm not sure what to feel about that. For example, an error code can be used to google for a problem, and if it changes, it people's lives harder. It's common to stick with the error codes (e.g. globally defined somewhere, which is the approach I'm considering).

Comment: @AndréFratelli: why would the error codes change: you simply define the errors in a single file, and only append to the file. You can make a simple pre-commit hook to enforce this.

Comment: Ah! It could go on a global file. That makes more sense. That way the order doesn't change. I was thinking of keeping manual track of the codes in a centralized way, you're suggesting the same but with a generator. Sounds worth considering.

Comment: Thought of another problem with this. What if the file is loaded twice?

Comment: @AndréFratelli: how would you load the file twice? If you import it a second time, it will not be loaded another time, then you get a reference to the module already loaded.

Comment: Not in that case, no. But I've seen a few examples. Calling `reload`, for example; although I think it would make sense in that case. I also saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798589/what-could-cause-a-python-module-to-be-imported-twice

Comment: I still have to test, but it seems like the `make_error_code` function would just be defined again as well and the errors registered in the same order, because the data was lost. It's not looking like an issue, actually.