# Python shared list between modules

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I want to create 2 modules (call them A and B): A writes values to the list, B reads those values from that list.
First module is constantly run and implemented using multiprocessing

My idea was to create a new module C that will be imported by A and B. A will then store values in a list from C. B then accesses the list from C whenever it needs.

The main reason for having that shared list is that I don't want A to directly talk to B.

So this is an example of code I have so far

```
#a.py
import c
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
  while True:
    c.add('value')

def run():
  p = Process(target=foo)
  p.start()
  p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

---

```
#b.py
import c
print c.list_of_values
```

---

```
#c.py
list_of_values = []

def add(val):
  list_of_values.append(val)
```

As far as I understand the problem is that when imported, it's a completely new instance of module C. Can I somehow make it shared?
The third module is not necessary if I can avoid it by having that *list_of_values* in A with a way for B to retrieve it. I tried that but also got nowhere. I can have a dependency on A in B, so B could initiate A and run it. Any hints?

If I can do something like that, it also works for me:

```
#b.py
import a
Process(target=a.run).start()
print a.list_of_values
```

I think my problem with that was that Process is run encapsulated, and is not affecting global variables. I then got lost with multiprocessing's Managers and Queues :)

Comment: afaik, modules aren't imported twice. They are kept in sys.modules, if a module you want to `import ` is found there, it won't get imported another time [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029523/how-to-prevent-a-module-from-being-imported-twice)

Comment: @WorldSEnder I might be completely wrong on the reason why this isn't working, but when I print the list from b.py it's empty, but values are getting appended to it if I check from inside a.py