# Using Prometheus with Connexion - ValueError: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus, connexion

I get the following error message when using prometheus with connexion using python3.6/3.7:

> ValueError: Duplicated timeseries in CollectorRegistry: {'app_request_processing_seconds_sum', 'app_request_processing_seconds_count', 'app_request_processing_seconds_created', 'app_request_processing_seconds'}

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gevent import monkey  # noqa

# monkey.patch_all()  # noqa

import json
import os
import connexion
import datetime
import logging

from connexion import NoContent
from prometheus_client import Summary, Counter

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

REQUEST_TIME = Summary('app_request_processing_seconds', 'time spent processing')
REQUEST_COUNTER = Counter('app_request_count', 'number of requests')

@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def get_health():
    try:
        'Hello'
    except Exception:
        return connexion.problem(503, "Service Unavailable", "Unhealthy")
    else:
        return "Healthy"


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
app = connexion.App(__name__)
app.add_api("swagger.yaml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run our standalone gevent server
    app.run(port=8080, server="gevent")
```

There is a swagger.yaml that is identical to:
https://github.com/hjacobs/connexion-example-redis-kubernetes/blob/master/swagger.yaml

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, you have named your file `app.py`. What happens it that when the swagger is loaded, the handling is specified as `app.get_health`:

```
paths:
  /health:
    get:
      operationId: app.get_health
```

And it loads (a second time) app.py to import the `get_health()` function.

The reason it that the main file is loaded as `__main__` module and thus get loaded a second time; see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029523/how-to-prevent-a-module-from-being-imported-twice) for more information.
Therefore, you end-up with defining your Prometheus metrics twice which doesn't sit well with the collector.

The most simple solution is to rename your file and implement your application in another file named `app.py`.