Python Global variable which appears to be correctly set is being return as None due to module being imported twice?
I was attempting to have a simple singleton in my 'context' module; yes I know singleton's are bad and I hate using one, this is the least-ugly of lots of bad options for moving forward with refactoring spaghetti code as we move to get rid of context entirely.
Here is my first version of the module.
_context = None

def set_context(context):
  global _context

  #assorted error checking you don't care about done here

  _context = context
  return context

def get_context():
  if not _context:
    raise ValueError("Attempt to call context before it was initialized")

  return _context

In my debugger I can se set context is called and sets _context as I'd expect.  However when get_context is called _context is None.  Odder still if I set a break point in set_context and In my debugger I try to check variables it says that _context is None but <my_project>.context._context has a context, even though I think those two should be the same object.
One I put a breakpoint on the original _context = None at the top of the class I discovered that line was running twice, once in the module that set_context is called and once in the module that get_context was run.  So presumably the problem is that I ended up with two copies of the module and the one I set the context in is different then the one I loaded from, but I thought the whole point of modules was that they only get loaded once?  How can I prevent multiple module loads and/or get my singleton to actually be single?

Practically as soon as I asked this question I figured out my own answer, and it makes me want to curse python.
I was importing set_context from <my_project>.context where as I imported get_context from context.  Because I used different paths to reference the same module python apparently decided they were different modules and imported it twice.  Using absolute paths everywhere fixes the problem by insuring only one copy of the module is imported.
It doesn't prevent me from wanting to curse at python for advertising that modules are unique while making it so easy for them to not be though....

I think this is wrong. It is probably because of this. Is the module with the code you posted in the question the main module?

Hmm... you can always curse Python if you want to, but you are to blame here. The import machinery of Python always ensure that a given module can only be imported once provided it has a unique path relatively to sys.path. The blessed way to accomplish it is to use packages or a custom PYTHONPATH environment variable. Any attempt to use anything else is the key for the problems you described...

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917320/17089544
