# Calling a method from a parent class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods, attributeerror

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax to call my method `__get_except_lines(...)` from the parent class?

I have a class with a method as shown below. This particular method has the 2 underscores because I don't want the "user" to use it.

```
NewPdb(object)
    myvar = ...
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def __get_except_lines(self,...):
        ...
```

In a separate file I have another class that inherits from this class.

```
from new_pdb import NewPdb

    PdbLig(NewPdb):
        def __init__(self):
            ....
            self.cont = NewPdb.myvar
            self.cont2 = NewPdb.__get_except_lines(...)
```

And I get an attribute error that really confuses me:

```
AttributeError: type object 'NewPdb' has no attribute '_PdbLig__get_except_lines'
```

Comment: Does from NewPdb import __get_except_lines(...) work?

Comment: The problem is solved now thanks to @hivert. I really appreciate everyone's help here, again, I learned something new (name mangling)! Great community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to Python name mangling for private variable (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references). You should write:

```
NewPdb._NewPdb__get_except_lines(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of putting a double underscore in front of a name is to prevent it from being called in a child class. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

If you want to do this, then don't name it with a double underscore (you can use a single underscore), or create an alias for the name on the base class (thus again defeating the purpose).

Comment: Ah, okay makes sense now. The intention was that I have a parent class  with this method, which (the method) should only used by myself in other methods. So I guess what I can do is just to copy&paste this method over into the child class, although it's not the "cleanest" way

Comment: @SebastianRaschka Or just not use two underscores.

Comment: I wanted to have those 2 underscores there for the "user" to know that this is one of the methods that he is not intended to use.

Comment: @SebastianRaschka The convention in such a case is to use a single underscore.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know that. Found a good thread here about singe and double underscore usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930144/underscore-vs-double-underscore-with-variables-and-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
super(<your_class_name>, self).<method_name>(args)
```

e.g.

```
super(PdbLig, self).__get_except_lines(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_PdbLig__get_except_lines'`.    I used `self.cont = super(NewPdb,self).__get_except_lines(...`

Comment: It's because double underscores cause [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html). If you want to keep your variable accessible, yet giving it internal meaning, add a single underscore - this is generaly known as `internally-used` indicator.