# TypeError: unbound method 'method name' must be called with 'class name' instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, typeerror

Hi I am trying to use the simpletmdb python wrapper for 'The Movie Database' API and I can't get passed this problem.

When I try to create the objects and call the method for getting movie info I keep getting this error.

```
in info 
response = TMDB._request('GET', path, params)
TypeError: unbound method _request() must be called with TMDB instance as first argument        (got str instance instead)
```

My code for calling it is:

```
from tmdbsimple import TMDB

tmdb = TMDB('API_KEY')
movie = tmdb.Movies(603)
response = movie.info()
print movie.title
```

And the neccessary parts of the simpletmdb wrapper are, the Movies class is a subclass of TMDB:

```
class TMDB:
   def __init__(self, api_key, version=3):
        TMDB.api_key = str(api_key)
        TMDB.url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org' + '/' + str(version)

    def _request(method, path, params={}, json_body={}):
        url = TMDB.url + '/' + path + '?api_key=' + TMDB.api_key
        if method == 'GET':
            headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content
        elif method == 'POST':
            for key in params.keys():
                url += '&' + key + '=' + params[key]
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', \
                       'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_body), \
                                    headers=headers).content
        elif method == 'DELETE':
            for key in params.keys():
                url += '&' + key + '=' + params[key]
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', \
                       'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(json_body), \
                                    headers=headers).content
        else:
            raise Exception('method: ' + method + ' not supported.')
        response = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
        return response

    #
    # Set attributes to dictionary values.
    # - e.g.
    # >>> tmdb = TMDB()
    # >>> movie = tmdb.Movie(103332)
    # >>> response = movie.info()
    # >>> movie.title  # instead of response['title']

    class Movies:
        """ """
        def __init__(self, id=0):
            self.id = id

        # optional parameters: language
        def info(self, params={}):
            path = 'movie' + '/' + str(self.id)
            response = TMDB._request('GET', path, params)
            TMDB._set_attrs_to_values(self, response)
            return response
```

The Wrapper can be found on here https://github.com/celiao/tmdbsimple
I am just trying to follow the example found there.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @qazwsxpawel on Github, @staticmethod decorators have been added to the TMDB class methods _request and _set_attrs_to_values.  If you upgrade your version of tmdbsimple, the examples should work in Python 2.7 now.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tmdbsimple

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with your indentation of the method `_request`. Try this code:

```
class TMDB:
    def __init__(self, api_key, version=3):
        TMDB.api_key = str(api_key)
        TMDB.url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org' + '/' + str(version)

    def _request(method, path, params={}, json_body={}):
        url = TMDB.url + '/' + path + '?api_key=' + TMDB.api_key

        if method == 'GET':
            headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content
        elif method == 'POST':
            for key in params.keys():
                url += '&' + key + '=' + params[key]
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', \
                'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_body), \
                headers=headers).content
        elif method == 'DELETE':
            for key in params.keys():
                url += '&' + key + '=' + params[key]
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', \
                'Accept': 'application/json'}
            content = requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(json_body), \
                headers=headers).content
        else:
            raise Exception('method: ' + method + ' not supported.')
        response = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
        return response

    #
    # Set attributes to dictionary values.
    # - e.g.
    # >>> tmdb = TMDB()
    # >>> movie = tmdb.Movie(103332)
    # >>> response = movie.info()
    # >>> movie.title  # instead of response['title']

    class Movies:
        """ """
        def __init__(self, id=0):
            self.id = id

        # optional parameters: language
        def info(self, params={}):
            path = 'movie' + '/' + str(self.id)
            response = TMDB._request('GET', path, params)
            TMDB._set_attrs_to_values(self, response)
                return response
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930223/2089675) that explains why single leading underscore methods are not imported when you use `from foo import *` syntax

Comment: I thought that could be it but it made no difference. I changed all the occurrences of _request with make_request and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple typo. Change:

```
    def _request(method, path, params={}, json_body={}):
```

To this:

```
    def _request(self, method, path, params={}, json_body={}):
```