# What is the sense of private names in a class

Tags: python, class

Can you explain why private class names are mangling. Consider the following class:

```
class A:
    __a=32
    def func():
        return a
```

`__a` is a private field of the class here. But what sence of renaming `__a` to `_A__a`? I dont understand what a sence of methods in python if we can't access from this body to class  field?

Comment: Python doesn't have private fields, it has name-mangling.  If you don't want name-mangling, don't use names that begin with a double-underscore.

Comment: @BrenBarn From python reference manual: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a **private name** of that class.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv it's "considered", by convension, but not really "private"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of name mangling is to prevent accidental name collisions from defining the same attribute in a subclass. Note that this has nothing to do with **preventing** access to the attribute. If you want to pretend that language level access control is a meaningful security boundary, go use some other language. Python's motto is that "we're all consenting adults".

Anyway, your example does work once you correct the syntax.

```
class A(object):
    __a = 32
    def func(self):
        return self.__a

class B(A):
    __a = 41
    def bar(self):
        return self.__a

    def bar2(self):
        return self._A__a

print A().func()
print B().func()
print B().bar()
print B().bar2()
```

`B().func()` still prints out 32, because it is accessing the version of `__a` defined in class `A`.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. In addition this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930144/underscore-vs-double-underscore-with-variables-and-methods