# Declaring private variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, private-members, public-members

I am writing a banking application in `Python`, and reading some source code from here [Banking Application](https://github.com/phriscage/banking_application/blob/master/lib/banking/balance.py). The `balance` class is defined below:

```
class Balance(object):
    """ the balance class includes the balance operations """

    def __init__(self):
        """ instantiate the class """
        self.total = 0

    def add(self, value):
        """ add value to the total
        Args:
            value (int): numeric value
        """
        value = int(value)
        self.total += value

    def subtract(self, value):
        """ subtract value from the total
        Args:
            value (int): numeric value
        """
        value = int(value)
        self.total -= value
```

**My Question**

Since balance details should not be accessed outside of a class, we should be defining the attribute `self.total` as `self.__total` since we should make it a `private` rather `public` variable? Is my line of thinking correct here?

Comment: There is no such thing as a private member variable in Python. Double underscore names are meant to avoid accidental overriding by a subclass instead.

Comment: Yep. You would still be able to access self.__total, but it would be under the name `B = Balance(); B._Balance__total`.

Comment: I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wi4bGaUTItY0)

Comment: How should I ensure that my attribute `self.total` is not accessed by anyone else then?

Comment: See [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346)

Comment: @python: you don't. You name it `_total`, which *documents* that other code shouldn't access it. But you can't *prevent* access, Python expects everyone to behave like responsible adults instead.

Comment: Also see [Does Python have “private” variables in classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641219)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for helpful info. Didn't knew that!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: there is no way to have a truly "private" class member in Python. The runtime simply doesn't support memory protection in the way, ex, Java does.

The double underscore prefix mangles the name so it includes the name of the class it's used in (ex, `__total` would become `_Balance__total`), but this is primarily used to allow subclasses to define names which appear the same, but reference different fields.

The standard convention in Python is to use a single underscore prefix — `_total` — for class members which should be treated as be "private" or "protected", then trust that the other developers will be adults and respect that (of course, this isn't always a safe assumption…)

It is *very* rare to see modern Python code use double-underscore attributes.

Comment: [Reference link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930144/underscore-vs-double-underscore-with-variables-and-methods) for additional reading.

Comment: You are saying there is no way to protect my variable `self.total` from unauthorized access?

Comment: Nope. As I say in the last paragraph, Python does assume that the developers working on code will not be malicious.