# Mongoengine 0.10.6 _data attribute of Document instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongoengine

I have some troubles with the `_data` attribute of a mongoengine `Document`instance after upgrading from version 0.10.0 to 0.10.6

I define a class inheriting from `Document`

```
from mongoengine import *

__all__ = ('User',)

connect('mydb')

class User(Document):
    user_id = IntField(unique=True)
    username = StringField()

    meta = {'indexes': ['user_id','username'],
            'index_background' : True}
```

Until now, I used `mongoengine` version 0.10.0

To access the dict of data  a `User`instance, I used to deal with the `_data`attribute.

```
In [1]: User.objects.first()._data
Out[1]: 
{'id':ObjectId('55b6290a10976a2a0908f8a3'),
'user_id': 1,
'username': "fake_user"}

In [15]: type(User.objects.first()._data)
Out[15]: dict
```

Now, I upgraded the version of `mongoengine` to version 0.10.6

```
In [2]: User.objects.first()._data
Out[2]: 
{"id": 'id',
"user_id": 'user_id',
"username": 'username'} 

In [2]: type(User.objects.first()._data)
Out[2]: mongoengine.base.datastructures.SpecificStrictDict
```

So `_data`attribute is no longer of type `dict`and my code breaks when I try to store a list of users in a `pandas.DataFrame` doing :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([u._data for u in User.objects])
```

I can't find any explanation in mongoengine changelog doc [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/changelog.html)

Can somebody explain me what is this `mongoengine.base.datastructures.SpecificStrictDict`? and how it works ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930144/underscore-vs-double-underscore-with-variables-and-methods) answer. Essentially though, names prefixed with a single underscore are not meant to be used by other code, they are an implementation detail and their use may change and break your code (as you have seen). I'm afraid this doesn't help, but does shed some light on why this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json.loads` to transform your document into the dictionary:

```
import json

user = User.objects.first()
json.loads(user.to_json())
```

PS. You shouldn't rely on private properties in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The `Document._data` becomes `mongoengine.base.datastructures.SpecificStrictDict`, through its repr is as the way you posted, but you can still use it as a dict.

`some_document._data['id']`

will get you a ObjectId object.

If you want an pure dict, you could convert it back to dict

`d = dict(some_document._data)`

The method also works if you previous versions of mongoengine.