# What attributes does python import from a module?

Tags: python

I checked some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python), but I have another question about which attributes get imported from a module in python.

For example, I have a module `temp9.py`:

```
a=10
b=20
print('a={0}, b={1}'.format(a,b))
def t9outer():

    print('in imported module')
    def t9inner():
        print('inner function')
```

Then I import this module like so: `import temp9`. If I get the attributes of the imported file using this command:

```
list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('__'),dir(temp9)))
```

I get this output:

```
['a', 'b', 't9outer']
```

My questions are

- `a` and `b` are global only in the scope of `temp9`, not across the modules (as the above answer says), so how does it get exported?
- Why was `t9inner()` not imported even though it is enclosed by `t9outer()`, which gets imported?

Comment: `a,b` are actually gloabal in scope of `temp9`. If you try to access them in your main module - you will get NameError. But, you can access them via `temp9.a` or `temp9.b`. And `t9inner` in not listed in dir of module, because it's in scope of `t9outer`. You can check this via `dir(temp9.t9outer)`

Comment: `t9inner` doesn't exist *at all* until you actually *call* `t9outer`, and even then the name is only in scope in the body of the function. You can think of a `def` statement as a souped-up assignment statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is the same for both questions. Everything defined at module level is imported; anything not defined at module level is not imported.