# Python change variable in another module and save it

Tags: python, package, global-variables, global

I have a simple python package named my_package with three files:

**init**.py

```
from .a import func
from .settings import var
```

settings.py

```
var = 1
```

a.py

```
import .settings

def func():
    settings.var = 2
```

When I add this package to PATH and import it I run below script, couldn't get expected result:

```
import my_package

my_package.func()
print(my_package.var)
```

I am expecting to get '2' but it returns '1'. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't `from` import variables. (Really, you shouldn't be using global variables at all, let alone sharing them across modules, let alone doing so with `from` imports, which are essentially incompatible with all that.)

Comment: how can i import settings.var without using 'from' in __init__.py?

Answer (score -1):

It happens because during `import my_package` a `my_package.var` is set to refer to int with value of `1`. After running `my_package.func()` this reference is not touched, however `my_package.settings.var` is changed to point at new `int` object with value `2`.

```
import my_package  # imports my_package.var with value 1 

my_package.func()  # sets my_package.settings.var to 2
print(my_package.var)  # prints 1
print(my_package.settings.var)  # prints 2
```

---

If you try to do the same with list, you can make it will work differently.
By not creating new object at `my_package.settings.list_var` but rather modifying an entry in existing list.

```
# __init__.py
from .a import func
from .settings import list_var
```

_

```
# settings.py
list_var = [1]
```

_

```
# a.py
import .settings

def func():
    settings.list_var[0] = 2
```

Now running the similar code will actually change the `list_var`

```
import my_package  # imports my_package.var with value 1 

print(my_package.var[0])  # prints 1
my_package.func()  # sets list_var to [2]
print(my_package.var[0])  # prints 2
```

Comment: what if 'var' is pandas dataframe? Should I insert that into list still?

Comment: nope, pandas DataFrame is also non-primitive, so it is passed by ref, just like list

Comment: what is the most conventional method of using package-wide variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python

Comment: Lists and ints are passed the exact same way. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html