# Stopping a while cycle modifying its condition (flag) from another python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

i am programming in python on a Raspberry Pi 3 and i have the following problem:

Raspberry has a temperature sensor and its data is printed on terminal by a simple module

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import Adafruit_DHT
    flag = True

    while flag:

        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

        print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

i need to stop the cycle from another module, setting the flag to a False value. How can i do this? I need to have this possibility even from a button on an android application...a nonblocking queue would be the best fit, but i haven't found nothing similar on Pika documentation.

Anyone could give me some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use flag as global variable, so you can set it false in another part of the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

as it seems you will read this value on request from other devices. i would suggest to use a webserver. I've used [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) for a similar project.

So, develop 2 endpoints: localhost:8000/startreading, and localhost:8000/stopreading which basically toggle the flag