# Python: Best way to structure module variables in imported module

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose i have a list of reference numbers in a file `numbers.csv`.

I am writing a module `checker.py` that can be imported and called to check for numbers like this:

```
import checker
checker.check_number(1234)
```

`checker.py` will load a list of numbers and provide `check_number` to check if a given number is in the list. By default it should load the data from `numbers.csv`, although the path can be specified:

```
DATA_FILEPATH = 'numbers.csv'

def load_data(data_filepath=DATA_FILEPATH):
    ...

REF_LIST = load_data()  

def check_number(num, ref_list=REF_LIST):
    ...
```

**Question -- Interleaving variables and functions seems strange to me. Is there a better way to structure `checker.py` than the above?**

I read the excellent answer to [How to create module-wide variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python).

Is the best practice to:

- declare `REF_LIST` list i have done above?
- create a dict like `VARS = {'REF_LIST': None}` and set `VARS['REF_LIST']` in `load_data`?
- create a trivial class and assign `clas.REF_LIST` in `load_data`?
- or else, is it dependent on the situation? (And in what situations do i use which?)

**Note**

Previously, i avoided this by loading the data only when needed in the calling module. So in `checker.py`:

```
DATA_FILEPATH = 'numbers.csv'

def load_data(data_filepath=DATA_FILEPATH):
    ...

def check_number(num, ref_list):
    ...
```

In the calling module:

```
import checker
ref_list = checker.load_data()
checker.check_number(1234, ref_list)
```

But it didn't quite make sense for me to load in the calling module, because i would need to `load_data` 5 times if i want to check numbers in 5 different modules.

Comment: Use pandas as you are using csv files

Comment: i am using pandas in `load_data`, this is a minimal example

Comment: You want to load the csv upfront, but you may use a different csv in some case. Is there a situation where you load more than one csv, or is it just one, but not sure which one?

Comment: i would like to have a default csv, but allow someone else to load their own if they need it.

Comment: sorry for the many edits, these comments helped refine what i was actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can load csv data easily with help of Pandas framework

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe=pd.read_csv('numbers.csv')
```

to check a number is present in the datframe by using this code:

```
numbers=[1,3,8]
for number in numbers:
    if number in dataframe[dataframe.columns[0]]:
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm not being clear enough. I'm not looking for a way to load data from Pandas or check numbers -- it's just an example. Will edit the question to reflect the real issue.