# Get globals() dict from other module

Tags: python, variables, global

I have follow [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files) to create a settings file with globals.

settings.py I have :

```
def init()
    global test
    test = True
```

in main.py :

```
import settings
settings.init()
print(globals())
```

I cannot see "test" in globals ! Any idea please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create module-wide variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977362/how-to-create-module-wide-variables-in-python)

Comment: Because it won't be in the globals of `main` but of `settings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, *global* variables are only global in the module where they were defined.

If you want to access the global variables of an imported module, you can use:

```
settings_globals = vars(settings)
```

Or if you only want the public ones (not starting with a leading underscore):

```
settings_publics = {k: v for k,v in vars(settings).items if not k.startswith('_')}
```