# Access vales of objects via index in Django

Tags: django, django-models

is there a way to access a value of an objectvia indexing without the use of dict()?

This is my model:

```
class state(models.Model):
    statecode = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='XX')
    statename = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

When I start the shell and create a new object...

```
>>> st=state(statecode="BO",statename="BOSTON")
```

...my object looks like this:

```
 >>> st
    <state: BOSTON,  BO>
```

What I now want is to access the statename via an index, so instead of

```
>>> st.statename
'BOSTON'
```

I want to access it with something like this:

```
>>> st[1]
```

but currently I'm getting the follow error:

```
TypeError: 'state' object does not support indexing
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why would you want to do that? what is the usecase ?

Comment: To compare two objects of the same type in a loop

Comment: For comparison see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513342/django-comparing-model-instances-for-equality