# remove duplicates from the list of a model instances

Tags: python, django, list, duplicates, instance

Based on the post: [Django comparing model instances for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513342/django-comparing-model-instances-for-equality)

I am trying to remove the duplicates from my list of instance (Which have not been saved yet and I assume their 'id' to be None)

the code is:

```
a = list()
a.append(relation_list.pop())
for x in relation_list:
    duplicate = False
    for z in a:
        if z is x:
        #or if z.attrib1 == x.attrib1 and z.attrib2 == x.attrib2:
            duplicate = True
    if not duplicate:
        a.append(x)
```

However, given the attribs being equal the line duplicate = True never get executed.

What am I missing?

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? (inspired from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897374/get-unique-values-from-a-list-in-python) using "in relation_list" either does not work.

Comment: Can you explain how `relation_list` was populated in the first place?

Comment: sure.  I have four models. lets say Action, Criteria, Danger, and Relation. Relation stores the intensity of danger that is associated with action based on the conditions stored in criteria.
So I annotate a 'Exist' field to Danger and loop through it to store the relations. (the_relation.Action_id, the_relation.Danger_id, the_relation.Intensity @DanielRoseman

Comment: Due to complexity of models and calculations 'Exist' annotation (among others) returns redundant relations which are identical.
I just want to save unique values.

Comment: @Azee `z is x` can be `False` even if `z` and `x` are equal. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python). Can you try with `==` operator instead of `is`?

Comment: @xyres I have already tried that. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know the result:

```
a = list()
for x in relation_list:
    if x.attrib1 not in [z.attrib1 for z in a]:
        a.append(x)
```

Comment: You made my day! @ahmad