# How to check custom Django model instance equality in tests?

Tags: django

I have a script which imports millions of records from a legacy database into a Django database using raw SQL for efficiency. The legacy database does not have ID primary keys, so these are created from a sequence when inserting rows.

I'm testing that this import process is working properly by creating rows in the legacy database, running the import and verifying that I get the proper Django objects back out. The last part of a test typically looks a bit like this:

```
actual = MyModel.objects.get(code=legacy_object_code)
expected = MyModel(
    id=actual.id,
    code=legacy_object_code,
    other_property=other_value,
    …
)
```

I have to pull the ID in from the actual object because otherwise there's no way the two objects could be tested for equality. But the problem is that `self.assertEqual(expected, actual)` always succeeds! This is because [Django object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513342/96588) is defined as having the same type and ID/PK.

My workaround to actually check the properties of the model instances is this:

```
def assert_model_instance_field_equality(self, expected, actual):
    expected_dict = expected.__dict__
    expected_dict.pop('_state')
    actual_dict = actual.__dict__
    actual_dict.pop('_state')
    self.assertDictEqual(expected_dict, actual_dict)
```

I couldn't find this sort of [assertion method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#assertions), but maybe I'm missing something. Is there such a method, am I missing something, or is this really the best way to check field equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`_meta.fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) property rather than `__dict__`

```
def assert_model_instance_fields_equal(self, model, expected, actual):
    for field_name in model._meta.get_fields():
        expected_value = getattr(expected, field_name)
        actual_value = getattr(actual, field_name)
        self.assertEqual(expected_value, actual_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful property! I'd still create a `dict` from all the fields so I could run a single `assertDictEqual` and see the full object difference.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@schillingt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261466/145) in that you should use [_meta.get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) over `__dict__`.  [_meta.get_fields()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) provides the fields that are *meaningful* from a Django model's perspective instead of just all fields that happen to be implemented via the Python `__dict__` property.

Instead of creating some *pseudo*-assertion, however, I'd recommend defining an "extractor" that returns the structural bits you care about in your comparison.  *Pseudo*-assertions get a bit fiddly when it comes to readability, and I try to avoid them where I can.

Here's an example of how that might look:

```py
def extract_structural_values(model_instance, ignore_pk='id'):
    field_values = {}
    for field in model_instance._meta.get_fields():
        if field.name == ignore_pk:
            continue

        field_values[field.name] = getattr(model_instance, field.name)
    return field_values
```

In a test I might use it thusly:

```py
# ...in some test class/function
self.assertEqual(
    extract_structural_values(actual_instance),
    extract_structural_values(expected_instance))
# or even
self.assertEqual(
    extract_structural_values(actual_instance),
    extract_structural_values(SomeModel(
        some_first_field='some value',
        some_second_field='some other value',
    )),
)
```