# Provide Global Access Point to an Instance of an Object

Tags: python, global-variables

Imagine a system (Python) where the different parts constantly interact with one instance of a given object. What is the best way to provide a global access point to this instance?

So far I can only think of building the (Singleton) instance in `__init__.py` and `import` the module as needed:

```
# __init__.py
class Thing(object, Singleton):
 pass

TheThing = Thing()

__all__ = ['TheThing']
```

Is there a better way to provide a global access point to `TheThing`?

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `singletons` in python. Python modules are great singletons (they are initialized only once and are available everywhere) and you can have a global variable in one, if you need it.

Here is explanation: [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python)

Comment: Interesting... let me ponder this.