# Placement of config file reading

Tags: python, configparser

I'm developing a CLI python program and I'm using `ConfigParser`. I know this is probably more to preference than anything else, but currently my configuration reading script is in `config.py` in a package. Would I be better off placing my configuration reading information in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference would to put it in `config.py` too, because `__init__.py` should be minimal, separate classes should be in separate files to lower maintainance overhead. So I would go ahead and create a `Configuration` class like this;

```
class Configuration:

    def getVersion():
        ....

    def getFoo()
        ....

    def getBar()
        ....
```

etc.

Comment: Should I be concerned about performance considering this class could be instantiated by multiple different modules?

Comment: You should absolutely make it a `singleton` so it can be instantiated only once. There are many ways to do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python