# accessing "module scope" vars

Tags: python, variables, module, scope, coding-style

I'm currently learning Python, and I have to work on a Python 2.7 project.

Accessing "module scope" variables in functions of the module itself is a bit confusing for me, and I didn't succeed in finding a satisfying way.

My attempts so far:

**Way 1:**

my_module.py

```
my_global_var = None

def my_func():
    global my_global_var
    my_global_var = 'something_else'
```

Here I think that confusing local and "module scope" vars may be quite easy.

**Way 2:**

my_module.py

```
import my_module

my_global_var = None

def my_func():
    my_module.my_global_var = 'something_else'
```

Here, the name of "my_module" could not be as easily changed as "way 1" when necessary. Plus, importing a module into itself sounds quite weird.

What would you recommend? Or would you suggest something else? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `Way 2`,  use `Way 1`.  Python scoping and assignments are interesting.  The interpreter will always search for a name from the inner most scope outwards when reading the value from a name.  When you assign a value to a name it does so in the current scope.  This means if you assign to `my_global_var` without the `global` keyword, your module will have two different `my_global_var`'s from the point of the nested scope assignment and beyond in the nested scope.  The global statement is simply telling the interpreter to assign values to the `global` scope for the name `my_global_var`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably want to read up on [Python's namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces). Way 1 is correct but generally unnecessary, never use 2. An easier approach is to just use a dict (or class or some other object):

```
my_globals = {'var': None}

def my_func():
    my_globals['var'] = 'something else'
```

Assignments always go into the innermost scope and the innermost scope is always searched first, thus the need for the global keyword. In this case you aren't assigning to a name, so it's unnecessary.

Comment: Ah. So dict values can be modified in function scope, but not raw string values. Python seems quite counter-intuitive here. Anyway, this works and suits exactly my need. thanks

Comment: Assignments always go into the innermost scope and are always searched first, thus the need for the `global` keyword. In this case you aren't assigning to a name, so it's unnecessary (Python will search innermost scope, and not finding `my_globals` eventually reach the module-level scope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations on this behavior. I understand better.

Comment: @FrostyZ You can modify any mutable object without using global keyword.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One question please: so using a dict is good just as long as you don't have any local variables carrying the same name as the dict? Doesn't that mean relying on a convention between the developers that might not be respected? I guess that preventing name clashes with _one_ global variable is a lot better than preventing clashes with an unlimited number of global variables. However, wouldn't it just be better off explicitly declaring `global` before using the variable(s)?

Answer (score 4):

Way 1 is the correct way when you absolutely *must* rebind a global variable. However you should ask yourself why you are modifying a global and whether there is something better you can do (such as encapsulating the behaviour in a class).

Importing a module into itself should be avoided as it is error prone. If the module is also a script you would sometimes need to import `__main__` instead, or if the module is part of a package maybe you should be importing `foo.my_module`. In short, don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Importing a module within itself can have unwanted side effects (like evaluating statements more than once.)  I would suggest using "Way 1" and a tool like pylint to help verify your code and enforce common practices.

PyLint can be found at: http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint

Answer (score 1):

Avoid setting globals at all. You can create new namespaces with classes quite easily, so use class variables if you must.

For anything serious you need a proper design with classes anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to create a singleton, and the recommended way seems to simply create a module (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python), so I would prefer avoid a class in this particular case.

Comment: @FrostyZ - I'd advise against using the module as a singleton, if for no other reason than it makes unit testing really difficult. See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python/6843917#6843917>

Comment: Even for testing, some singletons seem acceptable (e.g. a logger). See http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/root-cause-of-singletons.html