# How to use global variables with functions in separate files in python?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

I have two files random1.py, random2.py

random2.py has

```
def your():  
    global mine  
    mine = 10
```

random1.py has

```
import random2.py

global mine
mine = 4
random.your()
print mine
```

random1.py prints out 4 not 10.

My ultimate goal is to have functions that can take in any possible variable that has been declared and have the new values for that variable available after the function is run. I have all of the functions in a separate file though for organization. I noticed it works if I have them in the same file.

I am trying to replicate the functionality of procedures from Hoc

Comment: This code won't print `4`; it'll die with an `ImportError`. Anyway, this is a bad idea, and Python will not make it easy for you to do it. You're much better off using arguments to pass data into functions and return values to pass data out.

Comment: Keyword `global` has a misleading name because it accesses the variable of the namespace of the module (=script file) it is in

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you please directly use **random2.mine** instead of declaring it global again, which makes separate copy of mine variable in random1's namespace.

random2.mine = 50
print(random2.mine)


# Another way of modifying attributes of imported module is 
random2.__dict__[mine] = 100
print(random2.mine)

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841853/python-accessing-module-scope-vars
```