# How can I access a Variable from within a Fuction (Method) that's in another Module

Tags: function, class, get, attributes, var

I have 2 Modules, the first module has class `One` with a function which returns a value. The second has 2 classes `Two` and `Three` with functions. I've imported the class from the first module into the second.

In function `i` of Class `Two` I've assigned the function `x` from class `One` to `y`. from there I can access returned value by printing `y`, the function also returns a variable`type` needed else where in the program.

but also need to access this same variable `y` from within function `z` in class `Three`.

The method I've used in class `Three` returns an error. I've tried using `getattr` but found no joy. But I believe I may have been using it wrong.

The only other solution I've had is to return `y` along with `type`. Then assign the function `i` in class `Two` to `pop` in function `z` of class `Three`. But this calls the function from `x` in class `One` which means I have to enter another value then it prints multiple unneeded lines.

I've created a mock of this problem to try and find a solution but I'm a little stuck. I need to access the value from `y` in function `i` of class `Two` multiples times in a number of other classes.

Method one:

Module 1: TestOne.py

```py
class One():
    def x(self):
        Go = input("Please enter value\n")
        return Go
```

Module 2: Test.py

```py
from TestOne import*


class Two():
    def i(self):
        type = "Move"
        y = One.x(self)
        print("Test 1: ",y)
        return  type




class Three():
    def z(self):
        print("Test 2: ", Two.i.y)
```

Module 3: TestMain.py

```py
from Test import*


p = Two()

t =Three()

p.i()
t.z()
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\3com\Python> python testmain.py
Please enter value

Test 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmain.py", line 9, in <module>

    t.z()
  File "C:\Users\3com\Python\Test.py", line 16, in z
    print("Test 2: ", Two.i.y)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Method 2:

Module 1: TestOne.py

```py
class One():
    def x(self):
        Go = input("Please enter value\n")
        return Go
```

Module 2: Test.py

```py
from TestOne import*


class Two():
    def i(self):
        type = "Move"
        y = One.x(self)
        print("Test 1: ",y)
        return  type, y




class Three():
    def z(self):
        pop = Two.i(self)[1]
        print("Test 2: ", pop)
```

Module 3: TestMain.py:

```py
from Test import*


p = Two()

t =Three()

p.i()
t.z()
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\3com\Python> python testmain.py
Please enter value
1
Test 1:  1

Please enter value
1
Test 1:  1
Test 2:  1
```

Edit:
I've done a little digging and have a solution that solves the problem. using `global`. But have found a number of articles which say that the use of `global` can be somewhat dangerous if not used correctly,

Method 3: Working Solution. Meets desired output.

Module 1: TestOne.py

```py
class One():
    def x(self):
        Go = input("Please enter value\n")
        return Go
```

Module 2: Test.py

```py
from TestOne import*

class Two():
    def i(self):
        type = "Move"
        global y
        y = One.x(self)
        print("Test 1: ",y)
        return  type


class Three():
    def z(self):

        print("Test 2: ", y)
```

Module 3: TestMain.py:

```py
from Test import*


p = Two()

t =Three()

p.i()
t.z()
```

Output:(Desired Output)

```
PS C:\Users\3com\Python> python testmain.py

Please enter value
1
Test 1:  1
Test 2:  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done research and looking for similar problems I found that using a dictionary is one of the easier and safer ways to be able to access the needed information.
whilst trying to use global I found that I had encountered a number of problems also the program was not running as expected. With the current method I can access the values stored in the dictionary by importing them to needed module and can also easily make changes

This is the modified solution:

Module 1: TestOne.py

```py
my_dict ={'Go':None}

class One():
    def x(self):
        my_dict['Go'] = input("Please enter value\n")
```

my_dict is defined as a dictionary with a key:`Go` and the value set to `None`.
In function `x` of class `One`, `my_dict['Go']` is given the value derived from `input`.

Module 2: Test.py

```py
from TestOne import*


class Two():
    def i(self):
        type = "Move"

        One.x(self)
        print("Test 1: ", my_dict["Go"])
        return  type




class Three():
    def z(self):

        print("Test 2: ", my_dict["Go"])
```

In class `Two` I no longer need to assign `One.x(self)` to `y`.
The value of 'my_dict['Go']` in now accessible as it has been imported from the module 'TestOne.py'

Module: TestMain.py

```py
from Test import*


p = Two()

t =Three()

p.i()
t.z()
```

Output:

```
Please enter value
1
Test 1:  1
Test 2:  1
```

[Accessing "Module Scope" Var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841853/accessing-module-scope-vars)