# deepcopy does not respect metaclass

Tags: python, singleton, metaclass

I have a class which, by design, must follow the *singleton* pattern. So I went ahead and implemented it using a *metaclass*. Everything worked nicely until a bug was reported which, in summary, said that `deepcopy`-ied instances of my *singleton* class were not the same instances.

I can get around this bug by inheriting from a base *singleton*-type class, but I'd rather not, for reasons pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/312650).

A working example of this issue is presented below:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(SingletonMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.instance = None 
    def __call__(cls,*args,**kw):
        print "SingletonMeta __call__ was called"
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(SingletonMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance

class MyClass1(object):
    __metaclass__ = SingletonMeta

class SingletonBase(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        print "SingletonBase __new__ was called"
        if not isinstance(class_._instance, class_):
            class_._instance = object.__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instance

class MyClass2(SingletonBase):
  pass

from copy import deepcopy as dcp

mm1 = MyClass1()
mm2 = dcp(mm1)
print "mm1 is mm2:", mm1 is mm2

mb1 = MyClass2()
mb2 = dcp(mb1)
print "mb1 is mb2:", mb1 is mb2
```

Output:

```
SingletonMeta __call__ was called
mm1 is mm2: False
SingletonBase __new__ was called
SingletonBase __new__ was called
mb1 is mb2: True
```

Can you give me any pointers as to how should one resolve this issue? I'm running Python 2.7.X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs on the `copy` module say this:

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`.
>   [...]
>   The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. 
>   [...]

So if you declare these to return `self`, that ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to customize class creation (**not** instance creation), you do it in the `__new__` method of the metaclass:

```
def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
    dict['__deepcopy__'] = dict['__copy__'] = lambda self, *args: self
    return super(SingletonMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
```

and your test will give

```
SingletonMeta __call__ was called
mm1 is mm2: True
```

You need to define `__copy__` as well or even shallow copies will result in new instances.

Glad that my solution in that thread came in handy.

Comment: The only problem with this solution (and with @AKX 's as well, since those two are equivalent) is that if the user of the `SingletonMeta` metaclass needs a custom implementation of `__deepcopy__`, it'll be overwritten (if I understand correctly). Is there no way around this?

Comment: @dare2be Does it make sense to have a custom `__deepcopy__` on a singleton? A singleton means there should never be a copy. So `__deepcopy__` should always be the identity function.

Comment: I guess you're right. And if one _does_ need a custom `__deepcopy__`, they shouldn't be using a singleton in the first place. Since yours and AKX's answers are pretty much the same, I'll choose AKX's for being "first". And for RTFM. :P Thank you all the same!

Comment: @dare2be I assumed you knew how to customize `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__` behavior, but not how to do it inside a metaclass.