# How to import a variable from a different class

Tags: python

I have an instance of a class that i set the value to 'self.world' inside a class named 'zeus' inside a module named 'Greek_gods'. and i have another class names 'World' inside a module name 'World'.

How can i tell zeus to go to 'World' and get the instance self.world?

```
#module named World
class World():

    def __init__(self):
        self.world = Atlas()


#module named Greek_gods
class zeus():

    def __init__(self)
```

Comment: does instantiating a class inside itself work, seems like that would be infinite?

Comment: @dm03514: no, it will result in an infinite loop - in order to construct a World, you first have to construct a World.

Comment: Your going to get a RuntimeError by infinitely instantiating `World()`. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: It was a mistype. I meant to instantiate Atlas not World inside itself

Comment: Seems like you'd have to instantiate `World()` before you can access it's instance variables. Where do you create an instance of `World()`?

Comment: Seems to me that even if you could tell `zeus` to go mess around with `World`'s variables, that'd be a pretty bad idea since it breaks  encapsulation.  Better, i think, would have `zeus`'s constructor accept a `World`, or better yet an `Atlas` (since it really doesn't need a whole `World`).

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10942831/1290420) by @user1082764 -- it is courteous to cross-reference related/identical questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because you cannot know the world instance to be added in `Zeus` at the moment you create Zeus.

However, you can pass an instance of `World` for `Zeus`. There are various ways to do it:

- Pass `World` as a parameter to the constructor:

  ```
  #module named greek_gods
  class Zeus(object):
      def __init__(self, world):
          self.world = Atlas()

  world = World()
  zeus = Zeus(world)
  ```
- You can make `World` to create `Zeus`:

  ```
  #module named World
  class World(object):
      def __init__(self, world):
          self.world = Atlas()
      def create_zeus(self):
          zeus = Zeus()      # It would be better to pass it as a constructor 
          zeus.world = world # parameter but let us leave it simple

   # Using your classes:
   world = World()
   zeus = World.create_zeus()
  ```
- You can create *one* special instance of `World` in the world module:

  ```
  #module named World
  class World(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.world = Atlas()
  greek_world = World()


  #module named Greek_gods
  import world
  class Zeus(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.world = world.greek_world
  ```

I would recommend to use the second solution; after that, the first one. The third one, however, can be very useful, too, specially if, *by default*, you need just one world in your application (the so-called [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)).

Answer (score 1):

```
# module World
class World(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.gods_here = set()

    def leave(self, god):
        self.gods_here.remove(god)
        return True

    def enter(self, god):
        self.gods_here.add(god)
        return True

# module Greek_Gods
class God(object):
    def __init__(self, name, world=None):
        self.name = name
        self.world = None
        self.go_to_world(world)

    def go_to_world(self, world):
        if self.world is not None:
            self.world.leave(self)
        if world is not None:
            if world.enter(self):
                self.world = world
        else:
            self.world = None

earth = World("Earth")
mars = World("Mars")

zeus = God("Zeus", mars)
zeus.go_to_world(earth)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what you asked for - it goes to `World` module and takes `World`'s instance's `world` attribute:

```
#module named World
class World():
    def __init__(self):
        self.world = Atlas()


#module named Greek_gods
from World import World

class zeus():    
    def __init__(self)
        self.world = World().world
```

Although it may be done cleaner, if you could tell us what is the reason to do so. You can even shorten the code, if you assign `Atlas()` to the class'es property `world`. It will be shorter to reference it and cleaner, but will work almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a single instance of a `World` class across several modules, which you can do easily by creating an instance of the `World` class at the top level of your `World` module, like this:

```
#module named World
class World():
    def __init__(self):
        self.world = Atlas()

world = World()
```

Now when you `import World` in any of your other modules, you can use `World.world` as the only instance of your `World` class.  This gets a little confusing, because `World.world.world` is now the instance of `Atlas` that the `World` class creates, I would strongly suggest renaming something there.

Here is how your `Greek_gods` module might look:

```
#module named Greek_gods
import World

class zeus():
    world = World.world.world
```

Note that instead of putting `world` into the initializer for the `zeus` class, I made it a class attribute.  This is because it looks like you want to share this `Atlas` instance (which for some reason is called `world`) among all `zeus` instances.  For an example of how this would look, check out the following code (which you could put into your `Greek_gods` module to test):

```
z1 = zeus()
z2 = zeus()
assert World.world.world is z1.world is z2.world
```

Comment: I believe OP said that instantiating `World()` inside his `World()` constructor was a typo.

Comment: @JoelCornett - Ahh thanks, I did not see that edit to the question.