# Pythonic way to use class refernce in another file

Tags: python

I have a situation where I want to use class instance declared in one file in second file. As a small example, see the below code :

How I am solving it as of now?

File2 (To be executed):

```
# Prog2:
from prog1 import *

cls1.dict["name"] = "John"
```

File1

```
# Prog1:

class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

cls1 = Myclass()

import prog2
print cls1.dict["name"]
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import instance of class from a different module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942831/import-instance-of-class-from-a-different-module)

Answer (score 5):

Why the circular dependency?

File 1:

```
# file 1
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

cls1 = MyClass()
cls1.dict["name"] = "John"
```

File 2:

```
# file 2
from prog1 import cls1

print cls1.dict["name"]
>> "John"
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of `import` is to make functionality *available*. It generally shouldn't be used as a method of *executing* a procedure. Your "prog2" should contain a function with a parameter:

```
def execute(instance):
    instance.dict["name"] = "John"
```

"prog1" can then call this with the appropriate instance:

```
import prog2

class Myclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict = {}

cls1 = Myclass()

prog2.execute(cls1)
print cls1.dict["name"]
```