# Python Singleton: same object but values are different

Tags: python, singleton, initialization

I'm using a singleton for a python class like the following example

```
class GestionnaireUtilisateur(object):
    __singleton = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.__singleton:
            cls.__singleton = super(GestionnaireUtilisateur, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__singleton

    def __init__(self):
        self.compte = None
```

I can modifie self.__compte with the following method

```
def connexion(self, compte):
    self.compte = compte
```

On my first object GestionnaireUtilisateur(), I call the method connexion('toto') to modifie self.compte and the result is good. But when I call an another time the GestionnaireUtilisateur(), the self.compte is at None and not at the value I'm passing by connexion().

I make a test to not if the object are the same and they are.
I have this result

```
<securecloud.utilisateur.gstutilisateur.GestionnaireUtilisateur object at 0xb73aad4c>
toto
<securecloud.utilisateur.gstutilisateur.GestionnaireUtilisateur object at 0xb73aad4c>
None
```

Someone have an idee?

Comment: Use a module instead. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31875/10077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `__new__` returns an instance of the class, the `__init__` function is called on it.  So you are reusing the same object, but calling `__init__` on it each time.

It's better to do without complicated things like `__new__`.  Instead of trying to implement a singleton like this, just use a factory function to create and return one object.

Forced singletons like this are often a bad idea anyway, testing becomes more complicated, and it's essentially a global value, which leads to unwanted coupling.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the __init__ function if compte is present, to prevent overriding of the singleton attribute. But the second connection() will change the value of the first too.

```
class GestionnaireUtilisateur(object):
    __singleton = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.__singleton:
            cls.__singleton = super(GestionnaireUtilisateur, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__singleton

    def connexion(self, compte):
        self.compte = compte

    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "compte"):
            self.compte = None


s1 = GestionnaireUtilisateur()
print "'compte' before", s1.compte
s1.connexion('s1')
print "'compte' after", s1.compte

s2 = GestionnaireUtilisateur()
print "'compte' before", s2.compte
s2.connexion('s2')
print "'compte' after", s2.compte

print "s1 'compte' after", s1.compte
```

produces:

```
====================
instance s1
====================
'compte' before None
'compte' after s1
====================
instance s2
====================
'compte' before s1

'compte' after s2
s1 'compte' after s2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class GestionnaireUtilisateur(object):
    __singleton = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.__singleton:
            cls.__singleton = super(GestionnaireUtilisateur,
                cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls.__singleton._init()
        return cls.__singleton

    def __init__(self):
        print "Every time"

    def _init(self): # not __init__
        self.compte = None
        print "Once"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ned said, singletons are *generally not the right answer*. You get much more flexibility by using the factory pattern, which is basically trivial in Python. However, if you really need to share state, perhaps think about using the `Borg` pattern instead.

```
class Borg(object):
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = __shared_state
```