# How to initialize Singleton-derived object once

Tags: python, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple, elegant way to define Singletons in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python)

I have the following example code, in which I derive a class from a Singleton (hope it is one):

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class Tracer(Singleton):         
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init"

a = Tracer()
b = Tracer()
```

When you try it, you will see the `__init__` method of `Tracer` is called again. Isn't the sense of having a singleton to make another instance refer to the original one? I do not want to run the `__init__` method again, as it probably overwrites previous information. Maybe the singleton is wrong or it's use?

Comment: Why do you need a singleton? Just have a module level global which you assign one instance to and name the class with an underscore so people know not to instantiate it.

Comment: I prefer a singleton to rely on the implementation. I do not want to rely on people 'knowing' anyone's conventions.

Comment: @Alex Anyone trying to use your code is not going to presume it's a singleton, leading to confusion when they try and make more than one instance. Either way you will need to explain, I would argue a singleton is less clear and more work.

Comment: Of course, you probably don't need a class at all. A module-level constant is probably what you want.

Answer (score 6):

*My previous answer didn't work and I've deleted it.* However I've found a highly rated SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/355230) that does. The primary differences are that it uses a `Singleton` **metaclass** instead of a baseclass and overloads the `__call__()` method of its instance classes instead of their `__new__()` method. This gives it the control required over the creation process of instances of its singleton class instances. It would be possible to define an additional method for deleting one or more of these — say for testing purposes.

Another notable implementation detail is that the metaclass maintains a dictionary of `_instances` rather than something that can only hold a single value. This allows it keep track of an indefinite number of singleton instances (since it might be the metaclass of more than one since it's reusable).

Applying it to your sample code would be done something like this:

```
class Singleton(type):
    """Metaclass."""
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Tracer(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self):
        print("Init")

a = Tracer()
b = Tracer()
print('a is b: {}'.format(a is b))  # same object? -> True
```

Output:

```
Init
a is b: True
```

**Update**

The syntax for specifying a metaclass varies between Python 2 and 3. For the latter you'd need to change the `Tracer` class definition to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Tracer(object, metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Init")
```

Writing a something that would work in *both* version 2 and 3 of Python is possible, but is a little more complicated since you ***can't*** simply conditionally define it like this:

```
## Won't work ##

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:  # Python 2?
    class Tracer(object):
        __metaclass__ = Singleton

        def __init__(self):
            print("Init")

else:  # Python 3
    class Tracer(object, metaclass=Singleton):  # causes SyntaxError in Python 2

        def __init__(self):
            print("Init")
```

because the definition in the `else` clause causes a `SyntaxError` in Python 2 (even though the code in the block will never actually be executed). A workaround similar to what Benjamin Peterson's [six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/) module's [`with_metaclass()`](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass) function does and would look like this:

```
class Tracer(Singleton("SingletonBaseClass", (object,), {})):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Init")
```

This dynamically creates a baseclass that inherits the desired metaclass—thereby avoiding any errors due to metaclass syntax differences between the two Python versions. (Which it does by explicitly using the defined metaclass to create the temporary baseclass.)

Comment: @eyquem: Take a look at this alternative answer of mine.

Comment: You got it ! I didn't have the time to study all the other solutions that we find in other threads, then to compare your solution with other ones. But it works and I think that the ability to use a metaclass deserves an upvote.

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks...again. I did spend some time looking at the numerous threads and longish answers and chose this one...and many others did to the in the linked answer (which some other useful information). Sorry for wasting your/our time on my other, bogus, answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `__init__` is called twice, but on the same object.  You have created a singleton, but Python doesn't know it is, so it initializes each object that gets created.

If you want to pursue the singleton pattern, you'll have to move your initializing code into the `__new__`, or into another method that your `__new__` calls.

Keep in mind:

1. Singletons are the norm in Java, but are frowned upon in Python.
2. Singletons make your code harder to test, because they are global state carried from one test to the next.