# Is it possible for two singleton subclasses to use their own instance of superclass in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two singleton subclasses A and B, which data needs to be maintained separately. When one subclass A make use of superclass, some of the informations will be stored in list and dict in superclass. But when I try to invoke superclass from another subclass B the informations that are stored by subclass A causing issues.

Is it possible to have seperate instance of superclass for both A and B subclasses.

(I used self for superclass members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data members of base classes are **not** shared in Python

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Derived1(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Base.__init__(self, x)
        self.y = y

class Derived2(Base):
    def __init__(self, x, z):
        Base.__init__(self, x)
        self.z = z

d1 = Derived1(10, 20)
d2 = Derived2(30, 40)
print d1.x   # Will show 10
print d2.x   # Will show 30
```

The problem you're observing is probably related to something else

Comment: The OP's problem is likely because both subclasses are derived from the same singleton base class which probably -- who knows, there's no code shown -- only allows one instance of itself to ever be created.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem, partly because you haven't included any code in your question. So, based solely on my interpretation of the description you wrote, I think the following will address the issue of the two singleton subclasses interfering with each other.

A generic Singleton *metaclass* is used to define the base singleton class. The metaclass ensures that a separate single instance is created for each singleton class instance of itself -- i.e. your `MySingletonBase` in this case -- which is exactly what I think you want. The two subclasses derived from it, `A` and `B`, will inherit this metaclass from the baseclass and thereby will have independent instances of their singleton superclass.

This code below is based on one of my answers to the question:
     [*How to initialize Singleton-derived object once?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13793033/355230)

```
# singleton metaclass
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MySingletonBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
    def __init__(self):
        self.values_list = []
    def test_method(self, value):
        self.values_list.append(value)
    def total(self):
        return sum(self.values_list)

class A(MySingletonBase): pass

class B(MySingletonBase): pass

a1 = A()
b1 = B()
a2 = A()

a1.test_method(42)
a2.test_method(13)
print '{}, {}'.format(a1.values_list, a1.total())  # [42, 13], 55
print '{}, {}'.format(a2.values_list, a2.total())  # [42, 13], 55
print '{}, {}'.format(b1.values_list, b1.total())  # [], 0
```

The output illustrates that instances of subclass `A` are indeed singletons, and are separate from any instances created of subclass `B`, yet they are both inheriting `MySingletonBase`'s methods.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response,

The mistake that I made was I declared base class members list1 in wrong place,

```
class BaseClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    list1 = []
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.list1.extend([a,b,c])

    def printList(self):
        print(self.list1)

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass1, self).__init__('a', 'b', 'c')

class SubClass2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass2, self).__init__('x','y','z')

if '__main__' == __name__:

    s1 = SubClass1()
    s2 = SubClass2()
    s1.printList()
    s2.printList()
```

The problem has been solved, once after I declared list1 inside init method

```
class BaseClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.list1 = []
        self.list1.extend([a,b,c])
```

Comment: Showing some code would have helped answer your question, as would tagging or at least mentioning that you were using Python 3...