# Python: How to invoke a method from outside a class?

Tags: python, class

I have a really short and easy question:

How to invoke the send() method from **another python file/class**?
I want to send a message from another component to client (connection is established).

I thought Ijust have to get the reference of the singleton instance and then just "send" like this:

```
server = Server(ip,port)
server.send("hello")
```

If I do it like that, I get the error:

```
NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Maybe "self" is here the problem...

here is the server class:

```
class Server(threading.Thread):

    ##############################################################################
    # Server: Singleton Instance
    ##############################################################################
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Server, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance    

    ##############################################################################
    # Constructor of Server
    ##############################################################################
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print "[SERVER____] Creating Server Thread"
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.__reset__()  

    ##############################################################################
    # Resetting local attributes
    ##############################################################################
    def __reset__(self):   
        print "[SERVER____] Reset"         
        self.serverSock = None
        self.clientSock = None
        self.clientAddr = None
        self.clientData = None
        self.isRunning = None
        self.isWaiting = None

    ###########################################################################                
    def send(self, message):
        print "[SERVER____] Sending Message", message
        self.clientSock.send(message)

    ##############################################################################
    # Stop the Server: Close the Socket and Reset
    ##############################################################################
    def stop(self):            
        # Close The Client Socket
        if(self.clientSock): 
            self.clientSock.close()
            print "[SERVER____] Aborting Client Socket"
        # Close The Server Socket    
        if(self.serverSock): 
            self.serverSock.close()
            print "[SERVER____] Aborting Server Socket"
        # Reset the Member Fields
        self.__reset__()
        print "[SERVER____] Aborting Server Thread"
        self._Thread__stop()

    ##############################################################################
    # Server.start()
    ##############################################################################
    def run(self):          
        try:
            # Create The Socket
            self.serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print "[SERVER____] Creating Server Socket"
            # Set Socket Options
            #self.serverSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
            # Bind The New Socket
            self.serverSock.bind((self.host, self.port))
            print "[SERVER____] Binding Server Socket"
            print "[SERVER____] IP: ", self.host, " Port: ", self.port
            # Set The Awaiting Flag
            self.isWaiting = True;
            # Start The Server Loop
            while self.isWaiting:
                # Listen On New Socket
                self.serverSock.listen(1)
                print "[SERVER____] Listening Server Socket"
                # Accept New Connection            
                self.clientSock, self.clientAddr = self.serverSock.accept()     
                print "[SERVER____] Accepting New Connection: " , self.clientAddr
                # Set The Running Flag
                self.isRunning = True;     
                # Serve The Connection
                while self.isRunning:
                    print "[SERVER____] Want to recv message...."
                    try:
                        # Receive A New Data Block    
                        self.clientData = self.clientSock.recv(config.BUFFERSIZE)
                        # Process The New Data Block
                        if not self.clientData:                       
                            print "[SERVER____] Reset By Client Connection"
                            break
                        else:    
                            print "[SERVER____] Receiving Message: ", self.clientData
                            parser = MessageParser()
                            parser.parseSMMessage(self.clientData)                    
                    except socket.error:
                        print "[SERVER_ERR] Error at receiving data from client."                            
        except Exception as exc:
            print "[SERVER____] Server Thread Exception ", exc
```

Comment: Note: With this method of implementing a singleton, `__init__` will be called each time you get the singleton's instance. This is probably not what you want to happen.

Comment: Why is this a singleton? Calling `Server` twice will overwrite the singleton's attributes on the second call. It seems more appropriate to have a regular class. If you only want one instance, you just construct one instance and don't call `Server` again.

Comment: THANKS. I dont want to call Server() again, but how to access its send method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the singleton pattern is wrong, and this causes `self.clientSock` to be set to `None` before calling `self.clientSock.send`. The implementation is wrong because it will call `__init__` each time you get the singleton instance. Basically, what happens is:

1. You call `Server(...)` to get the instance.
2. `run` is called on that instance. This sets `self.clientSock`.
3. You call `Server(...)` to get the instance again. This will return the same instance due to your implementation of `__new__`, but `__init__` will be called on it again and `self.clientSock` will be reset to `None`.
4. Now the call to `self.clientSock.send` causes an exception.

I recommend avoiding using `__new__` to implement a singleton if you need one (though not using a singleton at all is probably best). Some other methods are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python).

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped me also a lot. I won't use a singleton anymore. Hm, you are completely right.


My intention was:
1.) Server runs all the time
2.) Clients connects to server and sends him a message with a string
3.) I parse that message. While parsing, I want to send some notification back to the client. Thats all. -.-