# Python creating single instance in whole module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am developing a python module. My module needs getting data from database various times. I am writing a data-layer class with sole motive of writing all the functions which hits DB at same place and calling these data-layer class methods from different method of my module.

I tried below code:

```
class datalayer:
   cur = None;     #Cursor which would be used by all methods
   def __init__(self):
     conn=sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME);
     cur=conn.cursor();

   def getEmpData(self,flowId):
     sql= "Select * from emp"
     cur.execute(sql);
     rows = cur.fetchall(); 
     return rows;

   def getManData(self,flowId):
     sql= "Select * from manager"
     cur.execute(sql);
     rows = cur.fetchall(); 
     return rows;
```

Once this is done I am creating instances of same class in classes where I want to hit DB, like:

```
class example1:
  def ex1():
    do_something()
    datalayerInstance =  datalayer();
    datalayerInstance.getEmpData();
```

But even if a do above each time the instance of data-layer class is created a new cursor object would be created. I want to avoid this and create a cursor object just once and use the same through the class. How can this be achieved?

Also, I tried using static method, but that too is not solving my problem.

Please help as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datalayer.py

```
datalayerInstance =  datalayer();

def get_datalayerinstance():
    return datalayerInstance
```

example.py

```
import datalayer
datalayerInstance = get_datalayerinstance();
```

Comment: hi @laike9m, Am I allowed to create instance of class inside class definition itself?

Comment: No, cause it's not defined yet. If you need to do that, perhaps your have a wrong design.

Comment: Can you please explain you answer in detail?

Comment: why dv? If anyone feels this is wrong please point out. @MayankJain when you call `get_datalayerinstance`, it always returns the same object, it's not hard to understand.

Comment: @laike9m You could just do `from datalayer import datalayerInstance`; no need for that function (other than that: Yes, modules are the most elegant way to handle singletons!)

Comment: @poke Sure you can do that.

Comment: Do you want me to write "datalayerInstance =  datalayer();" outside class datalayer inside same python file? In that case when will this be called? I got the point that get_datalayerinstance will return the same instance but not getting how to achieve it.

Comment: @MayankJain Is there any reason you can't do that?

Comment: I can surely do that but not sure when will it be called

Comment: @MayankJain When you `import datalayer`,

Comment: ohh.. Got it now. Something new for me :) Thanks a lot. I will try it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72346/discussion-between-mayank-jain-and-laike9m).

Answer (score 2):

You want a singleton

[Creating a singleton in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Logger(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton
```

http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Singleton.html

```
class OnlyOne:
    class __OnlyOne:
        def __init__(self, arg):
            self.val = arg
        def __str__(self):
            return repr(self) + self.val
    instance = None
    def __init__(self, arg):
        if not OnlyOne.instance:
            OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne(arg)
        else:
            OnlyOne.instance.val = arg
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a singleton. To do this you could override `__new__` so that everytime you have a new `datalayer` object created, it uses the same cursor.

```
class datalayer(object):
    _cur = None;     #Cursor which would be used by all methods

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._cur:
            conn=sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME);
            cls._cur = conn.cursor();
        return cls._cur

   def getEmpData(self,flowId):
     sql= "Select * from emp"
     cls._cur.execute(sql);
     rows = cls._cur.fetchall(); 
     return rows;

   def getManData(self,flowId):
     sql= "Select * from manager"
     cls._cur.execute(sql);
     rows = cls._cur.fetchall(); 
     return rows;
```

It should work although *it might not be the prettiest way of doing thigs*, there are others much more simple and elegant.
The only advantage is that this would not require you to change all your code.

> Answer adapted from this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810367/2549230

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting the cursor as an attribute on the `datalayer` class in your initialization method.

```
class DataLayer(object):
    cur = None

    def __init__(self):
        if DataLayer.cur is None:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
            DataLayer.cur = conn.cursor()

    def get_employee_data(self, flow_id):
        sql = "Select * from emp"
        self.cur.execute(sql);
        return self.cur.fetchall();
```

I changed some names from your sample to the more accepted standard in python. A thing to note is this sample will not be safe to use in concurrent environments.