# Create global object in module shared accross imports Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a database class in my module, `db.py` that I can only call **once**,  my design goal is to have one single database object and have that be used across all other modules. So `db` has the layout

```
#db.py
Class DatabaseManager

    def __init__():
        # initialize engine and database

db = DatabaseManager()
```

The problem is across multiple imports db is reinitialized each time, what I want to be able to do is something along the lines of:

```
# polygon.py
from db import db        

class Polygon:

    def something(self):
        db.commitChange(...)

# main.py

class GUIWindow:

    def something(self):
        db.getJSON(...)
```

How can I create **one** object for the entire program, and have all other modules importing db use that **one** object? I was under the impression db would not be reinitialized, but I am receiving the engine initialization output *twice*, here's an example and my output

```
# db.py
class DatabaseManager(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        print "hi"

db = DatabaseManager()

# polygon.py
from db import db

# main.py
from db import db
```

output:

```
hi
hi
```

Comment: With that code, assuming you're running a single process, `db` is *not* reinitialized each time; polygon and main will both refer to the same instance.

Comment: One possible solution is using the singleton design pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python