# Define a constructor in full classmethod class

Tags: python, constructor, class-method

Let's say I have the following class :

```
class Context:

    element_list = []

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, element):
        cls.element_list.append(element)

    @classmethod
    def remove(cls, element):
        cls.element_list.remove(cls.element_list.index(element))
```

This class is near of a Singleton class. The objective is to update `element_list` attribute anywhere in my program without passing a `Context` instance as parameter of my functions.

PyCharm signals me that I should define an `__init__` method. But I do not want to create two different instances of this class. I was thinking about creating a dummy `__init__` method like this :

```
def __init__(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("This class should not be initialized")
```

The question(s) is (are) : should I define an `__init__` method ? if yes how ? instead of using `classmethod` implementation should I use a singleton class (see: [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python))

Comment: Why not just use a module for this? Create a module, use functions and make `element_list` a global.

Comment: classmethods are bad, why not have an instance and pass list in the init?

Comment: @matino: classmethods are *not* bad. They have excellent usecases. This may not be it however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't really want to use a module for this, cause it's not really adapted to my global program. I'd rather use a Singleton class than a module.

Comment: Then just ignore PyCharm. But a module is the ultimate singleton, in Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In which case do you think that the class method are more adapted ? I though it was the right way to use them

Comment: You are just using a class to create a new namespace here and class methods enable that use. But classes ultimately are just instance factories so this use flies in the face of convention and expectation.

Comment: Related topic to the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **The `__init__` method is not mandatory**. You should only define an `__init__` method if you want to pass state to the instance being initialized. Looking at the code snippet you provided, it doesn't seem to be the case.
2. There are a few ways (hacks) to implement the singleton pattern in python:

   - Check out the [borg pattern](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/borg.py)
   - See this Stack Overflow thread on [Creating a Singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

   However, I think those methods aren't pythonic and should be avoided for the majority of the cases.

   As others have said, you could always **use python modules**. Python modules are one of the most awesome features of the Python programming language. They can have *state* (variables), *behaviors* (functions) and within one Python process execution, *a module will be loaded only once*.

   This means that, in a directory structure like:

   ```
   .
   ├── bar.py
   ├── foo.py
   ├── main.py
   └── singleton.py
   ```

   You could do:

   ```
   # file: singleton.py
   element_list = []
   ```

   And from the rest of your application you could simply import and use it:

   ```
   # file: foo.py
   import singleton

   def foo():
       # ... do complex computations ...
       singleton.element_list.append('baz')
   ```

   ---

   ```
   # file: bar.py
   import singleton

   def bar():
       # ... do more complex things ...
       if 'baz' in singleton.element_list:
           print('baz')
   ```

   ---

   ```
   # file: main.py
   import foo
   import bar

   foo.foo()
   bar.bar()
   # OUTPUTS: 'baz'
   ```

   As you can see, besides being simple and more elegant, using the module gives you all the usual list utilities to interface with (for instance, you could do `singleton.element_list[1:]` or `singleton.element_list + ['my', 'other', 'list']`, and so on). If you wanted to do this your way, you would have to implement other classmethods.