# Cross class variable only initialized once

Tags: python, variables, scope, global

I'm having some troubles with the scope in Python.
I initialize a variable (`basePrice`) in a class (`STATIC`). The value is static and the initialization takes some work, so I only want to do it once. Another class `Item`, is a class that is created a lot. An `Item` object needs to calculate its variable `price` by using `basePrice`. How can I initialize `basePrice` only once and use it in an `Item` object?

```
class STATIC:
    basePrice = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.basePrice = self.difficultCalculation()
    def getBasePrice()
        return self.basePrice


import STATIC
class Item:
    price = 0
    def __init__(self,price_):
        self.price = price_ - STATIC.getBasePrice()
```

Comment: Why are you using a class for this? Just do the calculation once and store it in a global variable, e.g. `base_price`.

Comment: Or, if the class `STATIC` has other behavior, maybe think about creating a singleton class.

Comment: About the singleton class, instead of a class you can dump `base_price` as a global variable in a module, which is loaded only once during the lifetime of the program. It is also suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python

Comment: That does make more sense. If you declare `basePrice` as a global variable in file named `STATIC.py`, you can just do `from STATIC import basePrice`.

Comment: I thought the global keyword only means the variable is global in that class or module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to write a module. For example, create the file `STATIC.py` as shown below.

```
basePrice = difficultCalculation()

def difficultCalculation():
    # details of implementation

# you can add other methods and classes and variables
```

Then, in your file containing `Item`, you can do:

```
from STATIC import basePrice
```

This will allow all access to `basePrice` from anywhere within that file.

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't thought of importing a variable. Thank you!