# How to setup an object before calling class methods like in Java/Spring?

Tags: python, python-2.7, initialization, class-method

I have an object that needs to be initialised by reading a config file and environment variables. It has class methods, I want to make sure the object is initialised before the classmethod is executed.

Is there any way to initialise all classes of this sort of nature? I will probably have quite a few of these in my code.
I'm coming from a Java/Spring background where simply putting `@Service` on top of the class or `@PostConstruct` over the initializer method would make sure it's called. If there's not a clean way to do this in normal Python, is there  framework that'll make this easier?

So the class looks something like this

```
class MyClass(object):
    def setup(self):
        # read variables from the environment and config files

    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, params):
        # run some code based on params and variables initialised during setup
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you need those methods to be class methods then? Sounds like you have some state to manage here.

Comment: It's a global state, like database endpoint and url for a particular environment the code is running in

Comment: Then make `setup` a class method too, call it always, and have that method check if a global has been set yet?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot have an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block which calls/does `setup()`?

Comment: Still, I'd encapsulate that in a class I create one instance of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was thinking that, is there a nicer way of doing it in Python so I don't have to keep putting `if not initialized: setup() `

Comment: @tt_Gantz: yes, make this a proper class, and create the class when you first need it. That can either be at import time or via a utility function that returns the singleton instance (and creates it if it doesn't yet exist). That is, still, a *test if global exists* approach though.

Comment: @Tersosauros I'm running a webserver and doing this in the not the class I use to run the webserver. I could add `MyClass1.setup(); MyClass2.setup()` etc. in the main class I run, but I'm looking for nicer way to have it defined in the class itself rather than always add it to the main class

Comment: @MartijnPieters so I either have to do it whenever I want to call the method, or inside the method. Is there a framework or decorators over the class that can help me keep the code a bit cleaner when doing this?

Comment: @tt_Gantz: I've always just written that myself. This is so simple, I doubt there is a library or framework for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a simple singleton implementation, which sounds like what you're trying to do. This post has examples of how to do it and some thoughts about whether you really need a singleton.
 [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Option #2.

```
class MyClass(object):
    # No setup()
    setting_A="foo"
    setting_B="bar"
    dict_of_settings={"foo":"bar"}
    # basically you can define some class variables here

    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, params):
        print cls.setting_B # etc
```

This option avoids the use of any *global* code at all.  However it comes at the price that your *settings* are no longer nicely encapsulated within an **instance**.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes.**

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self): #instead of setup()
        # read variables from the environment and config files

    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, params):
        # run some code based on params and variables initialised during setup
MyClass._instance=MyClass()
```

Basically, When you first `import`/load the file containing `MyClass`, it will run the `__init__` constructor *once* for it's internal `_instance`.  That instance (singleton) will then be accessible from all other class methods.

Comment: All you did was namespace the global. `global_var` is not much different from `MyClass._namespaced_var`.