# How to create a singleton?

Tags: python, import, scope, singleton

I was wondering if this approach for creating a singleton was correct.

`my_class.py`

```
class MyClass(object):
    def a_method(self):
        print("Hello World")
    ...

MY_CLASS_SINGLETON = MyClass()
```

another module:

```
from my_class import MY_CLASS_SINGLETON

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MY_CLASS_SINGLETON.a_method()
```

So this code is working for me, but my wonder is if the garbage collector could destroy the `MY_CLASS_SINGLETON` instance before it is used by any other module, as at the end it is just a temporary variable inside the `my_class.py` module.

Comment: It's not a "temporary variable". It's a name defined in your module. Python also isn't going to garbage collect `MyClass`, even though that's also just a named object in your module.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about the scope. And about the "singleton", it is true that I can create more instances, but in my case I don't worry about this. Thank you for the clarification though :)
EDIT: part of this answer was not for you but for @AnnetteC, sorry for the confucion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your implementation is not a save singleton as far as you can easily create new instances of MyClass. A singleton should avoid this by holding this instance by itself and just returning this instance - your instance is hold outside of the class.
(But I am myself new to Python and a the moment I just maintain procedural written Python code.)

But did you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had already seen it, but I found it "too complicated" compared to what I had in mind (and for my needs, of course).
And about being able to create multiple instances, this is ok for my case.
Thank you.

Comment: But what you are doing is not implementing the singleton pattern. You only provide a constant. Probably it is ok for your use case but if other rely on your code and believe that it is a singleton it can cause problems. Please, have a look on the ideas of the singleton pattern.

Comment: You are right, I just used the wrong name 'singleton'. The only thing I wanted from the singleton pattern is to be able to access the same instance from anywhere.